# endsWith in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, ends-with

How can I check if a string ends with a particular character in JavaScript?

Example: I have a string

```
var str = "mystring#";
```

I want to know if that string is ending with `#`. How can I check it?

1. Is there a `endsWith()` method in JavaScript?
2. One solution I have is take the length of the string and get the last character and check it.

Is this the best way or there is any other way?

Comment: This has got to be a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646628/javascript-startswith

Comment: Here’s a [fully spec-compliant polyfill for ES6 `String.prototype.endsWith`](http://mths.be/endswith).

Answer (score 1791, accepted):

**UPDATE (Nov 24th, 2015):**

This answer is originally posted in the year 2010 (SIX years back.) so please take note of these insightful comments:

- [Shauna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/570040/shauna) -

> Update for Googlers - Looks like ECMA6 adds this function. The MDN article also shows a polyfill. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith

- [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) -

> Creating substrings isn't expensive on modern browsers; it may well have been in 2010 when this answer was posted. These days, the simple `this.substr(-suffix.length) === suffix` approach is fastest on Chrome, the same on IE11 as indexOf, and only 4% slower (fergetaboutit territory) on Firefox: https://jsben.ch/OJzlM And faster across the board when the result is false: [jsperf.com/endswith-stackoverflow-when-false](http://jsperf.com/endswith-stackoverflow-when-false) **Of course, with ES6 adding endsWith, the point is moot. :-)**

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

I know this is a year old question... but I need this too and I need it to work cross-browser so... **combining everyone's answer and comments** and simplifying it a bit:

```
String.prototype.endsWith = function(suffix) {
    return this.indexOf(suffix, this.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
};
```

- Doesn't create a substring
- Uses native `indexOf` function for fastest results
- Skip unnecessary comparisons using the second parameter of `indexOf` to skip ahead
- Works in Internet Explorer
- NO Regex complications

---

Also, if you don't like stuffing things in native data structure's prototypes, here's a standalone version:

```
function endsWith(str, suffix) {
    return str.indexOf(suffix, str.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
}
```

---

**EDIT:** As noted by @hamish in the comments, if you want to err on the safe side and check if an implementation has already been provided, you can just adds a `typeof` check like so:

```
if (typeof String.prototype.endsWith !== 'function') {
    String.prototype.endsWith = function(suffix) {
        return this.indexOf(suffix, this.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
    };
}
```

Comment: Update for Googlers - Looks like ECMA6 adds this function. The MDN article also shows a polyfill. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith

Comment: What is my string contains multiple occurences of suffix?

Comment: @lukas.pukenis it skips to the end and only check one instance of the suffix at the very end. it doesn't matter if the search string appears elsewhere.

Comment: Adding a check for the situation when the argument "suffix" is not defined": 

if (typeof String.prototype.endsWith !== 'function') {
    String.prototype.endsWith = function(suffix) {
        return this.indexOf(suffix, this.length - ((suffix && suffix.length) || 0)) !== -1;
    };
}

Comment: What are the regex complications you referred to?

Comment: @AlexanderN: Of course, the `endsWithSlow` in [that jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/endswith-stackoverflow/3) does **something different** than the others: It's case-insensitive (and will fail if the value being checked has any characters with special meaning in regular expressions). Just the `toLowerCase` calls alone make it an invalid test relative to the others.

Comment: Creating substrings isn't expensive on modern browsers; it may well have been in 2010 when this answer was posted. These days, the simple `this.substr(-suffix.length) === suffix` approach is fastest on Chrome, the same on IE11 as `indexOf`, and only 4% slower (fergetaboutit territory) on Firefox: http://jsperf.com/endswith-stackoverflow/14 And faster across the board when the result is false: http://jsperf.com/endswith-stackoverflow-when-false Of course, with ES6 adding `endsWith`, the point is moot. :-)

Comment: If you want to implement String.prototype.endsWith in case it doesn't exists you really need to make sure that it is compatible with native implementation! Here you are omitting optional "position" argument which may break any third party code! Please use polyfill profided by MDN.

Comment: If you're following the `this.substr(-suffix.length) === suffix` approach, you may use `this.substr(-suffix.length, suffix.length) === suffix` to get the behavior `endswith('abc', '') = true`

Comment: Working Fine for IE also. Thanks :)

Answer (score 301):

```
/#$/.test(str)
```

will work on all browsers, doesn't require monkey patching `String`, and doesn't require scanning the entire string as `lastIndexOf` does when there is no match.

If you want to match a constant string that might contain regular expression special characters, such as `'$'`, then you can use the following:

```
function makeSuffixRegExp(suffix, caseInsensitive) {
  return new RegExp(
      String(suffix).replace(/[$%()*+.?\[\\\]{|}]/g, "\\$&") + "$",
      caseInsensitive ? "i" : "");
}
```

and then you can use it like this

```
makeSuffixRegExp("a[complicated]*suffix*").test(str)
```

Comment: This is nice and simple if you're checking for a constant substring.

Comment: lastIndexOf scans all the string? I thought it would search from the end to the beggining.

Comment: and what's the explanation? If I want to find the pattern "asdf" can I use `/asdf$/.test(str)`?

Comment: @TomBrito, `lastIndexOf` scans the entire string only if it finds no match, or finds a match at the beginning.  If there is a match at the end then it does work proportional to the length of the suffix.  Yes, `/asdf$/.test(str)` yields true when `str` ends with `"asdf"`.

Comment: @TomBrito, edited to make it clear what `lastIndexOf` does.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't understand what the slashes means in javascript. Does this have a name?

Comment: @Tom Brito, It's a regular expression literal.  The syntax is borrowed from Perl.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Regular_Expressions or for an unnecessary level of detail, see section 7.8.5 of the EcmaScript language specification.

Comment: @Mike Samuel: Good answer but I'm still left wondering if spinning up a new regex engine is really that more performant than a string scan, or if this were done properly, just calling substring (especially since your makeSuffixRegExp call is doing a very complicated replace which at the last is going to require a couple of full string scans and a bit of logic by the regex engine itself...)

Comment: @Tom Brito: Regex is a really awesome tool to have in your tool belt, when you need it, just remember not all problems are nails. [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) is a great place to learn more.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83, I agree re nails.  Performance-wise, on some older interpreters, (assuming the regexp is cached) the test was a single call out to native code, while substring solutions tended to require multiple slow interpreter instructions and expensive object instantiations.  That's no longer the case with modern interpreters.  Obviously, the only way to tell is to benchmark.

Comment: +1 for the cross-browser compatibility. Tested on Chrome 28.0.1500.72 m, Firefox 22.0, and IE9.

Comment: Cool, I didn't think of that. So simple & no monkey-patching. Thank you!

Comment: Using a regular expression is slower than just checking the end of a string even in fast languages

Comment: You can use something like: /kmz$/i.test(stringToTest) to test case-insensitively

Answer (score 94):

1. Unfortunately not.
2. `if( "mystring#".substr(-1) === "#" ) {}`

Comment: @Anthony, um... so use .Length-1, what's the problem?  if (mystring.substr(mystring.length-1) === "#") {} works just fine in IE.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 - that's exactly the problem: the '.length-1' syntax works in IE, and the '-1' syntax doesn't. It's something to bear in mind, so +1 to Anthony for the tip.

Comment: Couldn't you use `slice()`? It works for me in my quick IE7 test.

Comment: freaken IE. when will it die?

Comment: @ahnbizcad Your prayers have been answered now. RIP IE

Comment: @Sankar hallelujah, praise be the holy interwebs

Answer (score 69):

Come on, this is the correct `endsWith` implementation:

```
String.prototype.endsWith = function (s) {
  return this.length >= s.length && this.substr(this.length - s.length) == s;
}
```

using `lastIndexOf` just creates unnecessary CPU loops if there is no match.

Comment: Agreed.  I really feel like this is the most performant solution offered as it has early aborts/sanity checking, it's short and concise, it's elegant (overloading the string prototype) and substring seems like much less of a resource hit than spinning up the regex engine.

Comment: Also like this solution. Just the function name is mispelled. Should be "endsWith".

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 It's been a couple of years, but now this method is no faster than the 'indexOf' method mentioned above by chakrit, and under Safari, it is 30% slower!  Here is a jsPerf test for the failure case over about a 50-character string: http://jsperf.com/endswithcomparison

Comment: Probably should use `===` though.

Answer (score 58):

This version avoids creating a substring, and doesn't use regular expressions (some regex answers here will work; others are broken):

```
String.prototype.endsWith = function(str)
{
    var lastIndex = this.lastIndexOf(str);
    return (lastIndex !== -1) && (lastIndex + str.length === this.length);
}
```

If performance is important to you, it would be worth testing whether `lastIndexOf` is actually faster than creating a substring or not. (It may well depend on the JS engine you're using...) It may well be faster in the matching case, and when the string is small - but when the string is huge it needs to look back through the whole thing even though we don't really care :(

For checking a single character, finding the length and then using `charAt` is probably the best way.

Comment: If this.lastIndexOf() returns -1, you can hit cases where it returns true dependong on this.length and str.length. Add a test that lastIndexOf() != -1.

Comment: Why is the regex method broken?

Comment: @izb: The answers which are older than mine which try to use `str+"$"` as a regex are broken, as they may not be valid regexes.

Answer (score 31):

Didn't see apporach with `slice` method. So i'm just leave it here:

```
function endsWith(str, suffix) {
    return str.slice(-suffix.length) === suffix
}
```

Comment: You can simplify it a bit more:
  return str.slice(-1) === suffix;

Comment: This is the best answer. Not sure why it doesn't have more upvotes.

Answer (score 21):

From developer.mozilla.org [String.prototype.endsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith)

### Summary

The `endsWith()` method determines whether a string ends with the characters of another string, returning true or false as appropriate.

### Syntax

```
str.endsWith(searchString [, position]);
```

### Parameters

- **searchString** :
  The characters to be searched for at the end of this string.
- **position** :
  Search within this string as if this string were only this long; defaults to this string's actual length, clamped within the range established by this string's length.

### Description

This method lets you determine whether or not a string ends with another string.

### Examples

```
var str = "To be, or not to be, that is the question.";

alert( str.endsWith("question.") );  // true
alert( str.endsWith("to be") );      // false
alert( str.endsWith("to be", 19) );  // true
```

### Specifications

[ECMAScript Language Specification 6th Edition (ECMA-262)](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-string.prototype.endswith)

### Browser compatibility

[image: Browser compatibility]

Answer (score 17):

```
return this.lastIndexOf(str) + str.length == this.length;
```

does not work in the case where original string length is one less than search string length and the search string is not found:

lastIndexOf returns -1, then you add search string length and you are left with the original string's length.

A possible fix is

```
return this.length >= str.length && this.lastIndexOf(str) + str.length == this.length
```

Comment: You have earned the “Found a mistake in a Jon Skeet answer” badge. See your profile for details.

Answer (score 12):

```
if( ("mystring#").substr(-1,1) == '#' )
```

-- Or --

```
if( ("mystring#").match(/#$/) )
```

Answer (score 9):

Just another quick alternative that worked like a charm for me, using regex:

```
// Would be equivalent to:
// "Hello World!".endsWith("World!")
"Hello World!".match("World!$") != null
```

Answer (score 8):

```
String.prototype.endsWith = function(str) 
{return (this.match(str+"$")==str)}

String.prototype.startsWith = function(str) 
{return (this.match("^"+str)==str)}
```

I hope this helps

```
var myStr = “  Earth is a beautiful planet  ”;
var myStr2 = myStr.trim();  
//==“Earth is a beautiful planet”;

if (myStr2.startsWith(“Earth”)) // returns TRUE

if (myStr2.endsWith(“planet”)) // returns TRUE

if (myStr.startsWith(“Earth”)) 
// returns FALSE due to the leading spaces…

if (myStr.endsWith(“planet”)) 
// returns FALSE due to trailing spaces…
```

the traditional way

```
function strStartsWith(str, prefix) {
    return str.indexOf(prefix) === 0;
}

function strEndsWith(str, suffix) {
    return str.match(suffix+"$")==suffix;
}
```

Comment: You have to escape your string for regex escape sequences

Comment: Regular expressions are slow even in fast languages. Just check the end of a string.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know about you, but:

```
var s = "mystring#";
s.length >= 1 && s[s.length - 1] == '#'; // will do the thing!
```

Why regular expressions? Why messing with the prototype? substr? c'mon...

Comment: 'cus sometimes it's better when it's W.E.T.

Answer (score 6):

I just learned about this string library:

http://stringjs.com/

Include the js file and then use the `S` variable like this:

```
S('hi there').endsWith('hi there')
```

It can also be used in NodeJS by installing it:

```
npm install string
```

Then requiring it as the `S` variable:

```
var S = require('string');
```

The web page also has links to alternate string libraries, if this one doesn't take your fancy.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#endsWith):

```
_.endsWith('abc', 'c'); // true
```

If not using lodash, you can borrow from its [source](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/3.9.3/lodash.src.js#L10423).

Answer (score 4):

```
function strEndsWith(str,suffix) {
  var reguex= new RegExp(suffix+'$');

  if (str.match(reguex)!=null)
      return true;

  return false;
}
```

Comment: It's better if you explain ***why*** your code solves the problem. See the guide [answer].

Comment: the suffix argument should be scanned for regex expressions that have to be escaped. using indexOf or lastIndexOf seems to be a better option.

Comment: It won't work if the suffix contains any of these chars: .*+?^=!:${}()[]/\

Answer (score 4):

So many things for such a small problem, just use this Regular Expression

```js
var str = "mystring#";
var regex = /^.*#$/

if (regex.test(str)){
  //if it has a trailing '#'
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Its been many years for this question. Let me add an important update for the users who wants to use the most voted chakrit's answer.

'endsWith' functions is already added to JavaScript as part of ECMAScript 6 (experimental technology)

Refer it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith

Hence it is highly recommended to add check for the existence of native implementation as mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
function check(str)
{
    var lastIndex = str.lastIndexOf('/');
    return (lastIndex != -1) && (lastIndex  == (str.length - 1));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A way to future proof and/or prevent overwriting of existing prototype would be test check to see if it has already been added to the String prototype. Here's my take on the non-regex highly rated version.

```
if (typeof String.endsWith !== 'function') {
    String.prototype.endsWith = function (suffix) {
        return this.indexOf(suffix, this.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
    };
}
```

Comment: Using `if (!String.prototype.hasOwnProperty("endsWith"))` is the best way. With `typeof`, "MooTools and some of the other AJAX libraries will screw you up", according to "Crockford on JavaScript - Level 7: ECMAScript 5: The New Parts", at 15:50 min.

Answer (score 2):

@chakrit's accepted answer is a solid way to do it yourself. If, however, you're looking for a packaged solution, I recommend taking a look at [underscore.string](http://epeli.github.io/underscore.string/), as @mlunoe pointed out. Using underscore.string, the code would be:

```
function endsWithHash(str) {
  return _.str.endsWith(str, '#');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After all those long tally of answers, i found this piece of code simple and easy to understand!

```
function end(str, target) {
  return str.substr(-target.length) == target;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you dont want to use lasIndexOf or substr then why not just look at the string in its natural state (ie. an array)

```
String.prototype.endsWith = function(suffix) {
    if (this[this.length - 1] == suffix) return true;
    return false;
}
```

or as a standalone function

```
function strEndsWith(str,suffix) {
    if (str[str.length - 1] == suffix) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String.prototype.endWith = function (a) {
    var isExp = a.constructor.name === "RegExp",
    val = this;
    if (isExp === false) {
        a = escape(a);
        val = escape(val);
    } else
        a = a.toString().replace(/(^\/)|(\/$)/g, "");
    return eval("/" + a + "$/.test(val)");
}

// example
var str = "Hello";
alert(str.endWith("lo"));
alert(str.endWith(/l(o|a)/));
```

Answer (score 0):

all of them are very useful examples. Adding `String.prototype.endsWith = function(str)` will help us to simply call the method to check if our string ends with it or not, well regexp will also do it.

I found a better solution than mine. Thanks every one.

Answer (score 0):

This builds on @charkit's accepted answer allowing either an Array of strings, or string to passed in as an argument.

```
if (typeof String.prototype.endsWith === 'undefined') {
    String.prototype.endsWith = function(suffix) {
        if (typeof suffix === 'String') {
            return this.indexOf(suffix, this.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
        }else if(suffix instanceof Array){
            return _.find(suffix, function(value){
                console.log(value, (this.indexOf(value, this.length - value.length) !== -1));
                return this.indexOf(value, this.length - value.length) !== -1;
            }, this);
        }
    };
}
```

This requires underscorejs - but can probably be adjusted to remove the underscore dependency.

Comment: This is a bad solution, rather if you are already using underscore you should add this http://epeli.github.io/underscore.string/ to your dependencies and use their implementation: `_.str.endsWith`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(typeof String.prototype.endsWith !== "function") {
    /**
     * String.prototype.endsWith
     * Check if given string locate at the end of current string
     * @param {string} substring substring to locate in the current string.
     * @param {number=} position end the endsWith check at that position
     * @return {boolean}
     *
     * @edition ECMA-262 6th Edition, 15.5.4.23
     */
    String.prototype.endsWith = function(substring, position) {
        substring = String(substring);

        var subLen = substring.length | 0;

        if( !subLen )return true;//Empty string

        var strLen = this.length;

        if( position === void 0 )position = strLen;
        else position = position | 0;

        if( position < 1 )return false;

        var fromIndex = (strLen < position ? strLen : position) - subLen;

        return (fromIndex >= 0 || subLen === -fromIndex)
            && (
                position === 0
                // if position not at the and of the string, we can optimise search substring
                //  by checking first symbol of substring exists in search position in current string
                || this.charCodeAt(fromIndex) === substring.charCodeAt(0)//fast false
            )
            && this.indexOf(substring, fromIndex) === fromIndex
        ;
    };
}
```

**Benefits:**

- This version is not just re-using indexOf.
- Greatest performance on long strings. Here is a speed test http://jsperf.com/starts-ends-with/4
- Fully compatible with ecmascript specification. It passes the [tests](https://github.com/monolithed/ECMAScript-6/blob/master/tests/String.js)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use regular expressions. They are slow even in fast languages. Just write a function that checks the end of a string. This library has nice examples: [groundjs/util.js](https://github.com/danielnuriyev/groundjs/blob/master/util.js).
Be careful adding a function to String.prototype. This code has nice examples of how to do it: [groundjs/prototype.js](https://github.com/danielnuriyev/groundjs/blob/master/prototype.js)
In general, this is a nice language-level library: [groundjs](https://github.com/danielnuriyev/groundjs/blob/master/ground.js)
You can also take a look at lodash

Answer (score 0):

For coffeescript

```
String::endsWith = (suffix) ->
  -1 != @indexOf suffix, @length - suffix.length
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the implementation of `endsWith`:

```js
String.prototype.endsWith = function (str) {
  return (this.length >= str.length) && (this.substr(this.length - str.length) === str);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

7 years old post, but I was not able to understand top few posts, because they are complex. So, I wrote my own solution:

```
function strEndsWith(str, endwith)
{
    var lastIndex = url.lastIndexOf(endsWith);
    var result = false;
    if (lastIndex > 0 && (lastIndex + "registerc".length) == url.length)
    {
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}
```