# JavaScript indexOf to ignore Case

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find if an image has in its source name `noPic` which can be in upper or lower case.

```
var noPic = largeSrc.indexOf("nopic");
```

Should I write :

```
var noPic = largeSrc.toLowerCase().indexOf("nopic");
```

But this solution doesn't work...

Comment: What is largeSrc?  Are you sure it is a string?

Comment: Use the debugger. Set a breakpoint on the `var noPic = ...` line and see what the type and value of `largeSrc` are. Or you can put a `console.log( typeof largeSrc, largeSrc );` before your line. But from the question, it sounds like you may not be familiar with the interactive JavaScript debugger in your browser. I highly recommend getting familiar with it. For example: [Chrome DevTools tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use regex with a case-insensitive modifier - admittedly not necessarily as fast as indexOf.

```
var noPic = largeSrc.search(/nopic/i);
```

Comment: According to: http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-tolowercase-then-regex/2 the regex method is faster than toLower()

Comment: the regex method ends up being slower if the search term comes from user input, see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/19920595/1333402

Comment: @ppumkin It will if you need to do this in a tight loop.

Comment: I'm curious as to why, though, his initial method did not work.

Comment: Up until Chrome 64, the regex approach might have held its own, but as of 69, `toLowerCase()` is 31 times faster, according to http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-tolowercase-then-regex/2.

Comment: ppumkin Not sure if that's a hypothetical 50ms, but it's going to be far less than that even. The perf linked to by Mike is showing an incredible difference, but in my environment it was 7M operations per second vs. 347M operations per second. It's theoretically a HUGE difference in performance; however, I agree with what you're driving at: "You mean I can still do this 7 million times in a second? I think I'm OK." Especially if it's client side rather than having to scale to large numbers of connections server-side.

Answer (score 24):

No, there is no case-insensitive way to call that function.  Perhaps the reason your second example doesn't work is because you are missing a call to the `text()` function.

Try this:

```
var search = "nopic";
var noPic = largeSrc.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase());
```

Comment: note that indexOf() can be slow for large strings, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4579228/1333402

Answer (score 5):

Note that if the search string is from user input you'll need to escape the special regexp characters.

Here's what it would look like:

```
var search = getUserInput();

/* case-insensitive search takes around 2 times more than simple indexOf() */
var regex = RegExp(search.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'), "i");

var noPic = testString.search(regex);
```

See the updated jsperf: http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-tolowercase-then-regex/4

*footnote: regexp escaping from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711/1333402*

Comment: I edited out the part where you were saying that escaped regex makes search slower than `toLowerCase()`  as I believe this is the one right solution and I have the data confirming that regex search actually scales much more efficiently than `toLowerCase()`. In my use case it was 100 MiB long text and around 20 characters lookup substring: `toLowerCase()` call alone took more than a second of CPU time, while direct regex search ran withing 30 ms, that's just slighty longer than a regular `indexOf()`.

Answer (score 4):

Try with:

```
var lowerCaseLargeSrc = largeSrc.toLowerCase();
var noPic = lowerCaseLargeSrc.indexOf("nopic");
```

Comment: Better solution than regex imo.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will only work if largeSrc is already a string. You might be getting an input that's an html element instead. So, use jQuery to resolve any potential input element into the text that's inside it. Example:

```
var noPic = largeSrc.text().toLowerCase().indexOf("nopic");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using findIndex instead that way you can do all your toLowerCase() inside the callback. Worked great for me:

```
// Not Supported in IE 6-11
const arr = ['HELLO', 'WORLD'];
const str = 'world';

const index = arr.findIndex(element => {
  return element.toLowerCase() === str.toLowerCase();
});

console.log(index); // ️ 1

if (index !== -1) {
  // ️ string is in the array
}
```

Credit:
https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-make-array-indexof-case-insensitive