# Case insensitive indexOf with grep

Tags: jquery

I'm using IndexOf and $.grep in jquery to search a list of values.  I need a case insensitive search, but I am getting case sensitivity.  I've found similar solutions here on StackOverflow, but hey did not meet my needs.  For example none of the solutions found at this link solved my problem: [javascript indexOf to ignore Case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245930/javascript-indexof-to-ignore-case)

Here is the code:

```
var searchValue = "abc";    
var matches = $.grep(listView.dataSource.view(), function (e) { return e.CategoryName.indexOf(searchValue) >= 0; });
```

Comment: `e.CategoryName.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue.toLowerCase())`

Comment: Perfect thanks.  The difference between your solution and the one that I referenced above (which did not work for me) is the .text() in the other solution.

Comment: Being able to apply answers that differ by that little is a key ability in programming. I would consider this a duplicate of that other question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually in cases where I'm matching the string I'll force it to lower case: `str.toLowerCase();`

So you want to do that on both sides:

```
var searchValue = "abc";    
var matches = $.grep(listView.dataSource.view(), function (e) { return e.CategoryName.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue.toLowerCase()) >= 0; });
```

You can use `toUpperCase()` too but most people use `toLowerCase()`;

Comment: ah beaten to it in the comments