# How to check if a string contains http:// at the start

Tags: regex, string

I want to be able to check a string to see if it has http:// at the start and if not to add it.

```
if (regex expression){
string = "http://"+string;
}
```

Does anyone know the regex expression to use?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If you don't need a regex to do this (depending on what language you're using), you could simply look at the initial characters of your string. For example:

```
// C#
if (!str.StartsWith("http://"))
    str = "http://" + str;

// Java
if (!str.startsWith("http://"))
    str = "http://" + str;

// JavaScript/TypeScript
if (str.substring(0, 7) !== 'http://')
    str = 'http://' + str;
```

Comment: May many, many upvotes be bestowed upon you. Sometimes, regexes are overkill.

Comment: Thank you for the blessing. Yes, sometimes powerful language features are overused. Regex's are not as fast as simple string operations.

Comment: @Ra91 - I added a JavaScript example, which does work in IE.

Answer (score 8):

Should be:

```
/^http:\/\//
```

And remember to use this with `!` or `not` (you didn't say which programming language), since you are looking for items which don't match.

Answer (score 7):

In JavaScript:

```
if(!(/^http:\/\//.test(url)))
{
    string = "http://" + string;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var url = "http://abcd";
var pattern = /^((http|https|ftp):\/\/)/;

if(!pattern.test(url)) {
    url = "http://" + url;
}

alert(url);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. - [From Review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/13275385)

Comment: Thank you so much! It helps me improve in processing

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work `^(https?://)`

Answer (score 2):

```
yourString = yourString.StartWith("http://") ? yourString : "http://" + yourString
```

Is more sexy

Answer (score 1):

```
 /^http:\/\//
```

Answer (score 0):

If javascript is the language needed here, then look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646628/javascript-startswith) which adds "startswith" property to the string type.

Answer (score 0):

For me, with PHP these are the 2 I use just adding them here for completeness.

```
$__regex_url_no_http = "@[-a-zA-Z0-9\@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()\@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)@";

$__regex_url_http = "@https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9\@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()\@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)@";
```

I have a function like this to check:

```
/**
 * Filters a url @param url If @param protocol is true
 * then it will check if the url contains the protocol
 * portion in the url if it doesn't then false will be
 * returned.
 * 
 * @param string $url
 * @param boolean $protocol
 * @return boolean
 */   
public function filter_url($url, $protocol=false){
  $response = FALSE;

  $regex = $protocol == false ? $this->__regex_url_no_http:$this->__regex_url_http;

  if(preg_match($regex, $url)){
    $response = TRUE;
  }

  return $response;
}
```

I didn't create the regex. I found them someplace but seem to be compliant