# How can I check if the contents of a variable start with something?

Tags: javascript

I would like to do something like this:

```
if (idCity == 'AB*') {
   //  do something
}
```

In other words. I want to check that idCity starts with the string "AB". How can I do this in Javascript?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646628/javascript-startswith

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript - check if string begins with something?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767246/javascript-check-if-string-begins-with-something)

Comment: How about reading through the [list of string manipulation methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Methods_unrelated_to_HTML) until you find one that seems to do the trick?

Answer (score 3):

```
if (idCity.substr(0,2) == 'AB') {
   alert('the string starts with AB');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(idCity.substr(0,2)=='AB'){
}
```

If 'AB' is not constant string, you may use

```
if(idCity.substr(0,start.length)==start){
}
```

Comment: `.length` is a property, not a method.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(idCity.indexOf('AB') == 0)
{
  alert('the string starts with AB');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
idCity = 'AB767 something';

function startWith(searchString){
    if (idCity.indexOf(searchString) == 0){
         return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: just `return idCity.indexOf(searchString) == 0` seems to be much simpler