# Use "^" to check if string begins with another string?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript - check if string begins with something?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767246/javascript-check-if-string-begins-with-something)

I've read in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767246/javascript-check-if-string-begins-with-something) that you can use ^= to check if a string begins with something.

I've fiddled with this example:

```
var foo = "something-something";
if(foo ^= "something") {
    alert("works!");
}
else{
    alert("doesn't work :(");
}
```

And it doesn't work - does anyone how to do this?

jsfiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/timkl/M6dEM/

Comment: Did you read any of the *answers* in that post you linked to?

Comment: I've undone the edit that added the jQuery tag since there is no mention of jQuery anywhere in the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
   var foo = "something-something";
if(foo.indexOf("something") === 0) {
    alert("works!");
}
else{
    alert("doesn't work :(");
}
```

See updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/M6dEM/3/

Answer (score 10):

I think, perhaps, you were thinking of:

```
var x = "hello world!"
if (x.match(/^hello/)) {
   alert("I start with it!")
}
```

This uses an anchored (`^`) regular expression: it must find "hello" *at the start* of the input to match.

On the other hand, `x ^= "foo"` is the same as `x = x ^ "foo"`, or a bit-wise exclusive or. In this case that is equivalent to `x = "something-something" ^ "something"` -> `x = 0 ^ 0` -> `0` (which is a falsey value, and never true).

Happy coding.

Answer (score 5):

Use substring() method.

```
if(foo.substring(0,"something".length) == "something") {
    alert("works!");
}
else{
    alert("doesn't work :(");
}
```

I edited my answer and replaced "9" with "something".length so now there's no hardcode anymore.