# JavaScript string matching only at the start versus using indexOf?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, indexof

I currently am matching user input as follows:

```
user_input = "upload a file"

if ( "upload a file".indexOf(user_input.toLowerCase()) > -1 ) {}
```

This work fine but the problem is, it matches "a file" which I don't want. I want it to only match if the beginning is correct.

This should match:

```
"upload"
"u"
"upload a"
```

This should not match, because the string does not match from the start:

```
"a"
"file"
```

Are there any suggestions on how to make this happen with `indexOf`?

Comment: Compare the return value of indexOf to zero: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767246/javascript-check-if-string-begins-with-something

Comment: Vikdor, that doesn't work because indexOf matches anywhere in the string, which I don't want. I don't wnat anywhere in the string only from the start.

Comment: @Sarahpre Vikdor's point is that if it does match at the _start of the string_ the result will be zero

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`indexOf` return the index of the match, so if you want to test if it match at the beginning just check if it returns 0

```
user_input = "upload a file"
if ( "upload a file".indexOf(user_input.toLowerCase()) == 0 ) {}
```

Comment: For the sake of JS sanity, that should probably be `===`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
user_input = "upload a file"
if ( "upload a file".**substr**(0, user_input.length) == user_input.toLowerCase()) {}
</script>
```

Use the inputs to your advantage...

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp

Grab first X characters of the string, and make sure the whole string matches or any number of the characters you would like.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe means you want compare with zero:

```
if ( "upload a file".indexOf(user_input.toLowerCase()) == 0) { }
```