# Move downloaded files in to specific folder

Tags: batch-file, jscript

My task is to download files from the server using a .bat file.
Now here is my problem:

I can download the files manually. Now i want to make it further automated, once i run the .bat file my jscript should run a loop searching for files with specific format (????_dd-MM-YYYY.txt).

Now this (????) is a prefix..i have comp_,faqs_ and so on.

I wanna move comp_ files to the Complaint folder. faqs_ to the Faq folder.( I think i can solve this part)

Now can someone guide me on how to find files with the specific format using jscript.( do i use regex?)

Any help would be wonderful

ps: I don't wanna use wildcards

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript - check if string begins with something?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767246/javascript-check-if-string-begins-with-something)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look into "starts-with" (or maybe it is "startswith") method.