# How to know that a string starts/ends with a specific string in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I want to know if a string starts with the specified character/string or ends with it in jQuery.

**For Example:**

```
var str = 'Hello World';

if( str starts with 'Hello' ) {
   alert('true');
} else {
   alert('false');
}

if( str ends with 'World' ) {
   alert('true');
} else {
   alert('false');
}
```

If there is not any function then any alternative ?

Comment: Use [ES6 new features](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25797279/1090562)

Comment: Yeah well, or don't use ES6 yet if you have users that use IE older than Edge.

Answer (score 406, accepted):

One option is to use regular expressions:

```
if (str.match("^Hello")) {
   // do this if begins with Hello
}

if (str.match("World$")) {
   // do this if ends in world
}
```

Comment: in jQuery I tried str.startsWith('some checking string ..') this gave me an error saying, startsWith method not found.. :( but str.match worked. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Just be careful the string you are inspecting does not contain any regex reserved characters.

Comment: Passing a regex object instead of a regex string seems to solve the problem @nokturnal mentions: `str.match(/^Hello/)`
But the form `/regex/.test(str)` is even better for this particular case, per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940137/regex-test-v-s-string-match-to-know-if-a-string-matches-a-regular-expression

Comment: This would return matched string, but not boolean value.

Comment: `var isUnavailable = $("#StatusId option:selected").text().match("^Unavailable - ");` - why does this return null when the selected option is "Unavailable - Other" ?

Answer (score 104):

For startswith, you can use indexOf:

```
if(str.indexOf('Hello') == 0) {
```

...

[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646628/javascript-startswith)

and you can do the maths based on string length to determine 'endswith'.

```
if(str.lastIndexOf('Hello') == str.length - 'Hello'.length) {
```

Comment: you might want to use `lastIndexOf()` for the endswith ;)

Comment: Careful, IndexOf is not Supported in IE8 Browser. Same with lastIndexOf.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I was referring to Array.prototype.indexOf() that is supported only for iE9+ and not String.prototype.indexOf() that's IE4+

Comment: A much safer answer than using regular expressions for such a simple use case. Should probably be accepted answer.

Comment: The code for 'endswith' is faulty. When checking for a string that does not appear in the string and that has the length = (word - 1).

E. g. `("1234".lastIndexOf('Hello') == "1234".length - 'Hello'.length)` results in true.

Answer (score 23):

There is no need of jQuery to do that. You could code a jQuery wrapper but it would be useless so you should better use

```
var str = "Hello World";

window.alert("Starts with Hello ? " + /^Hello/i.test(str));        

window.alert("Ends with Hello ? " + /Hello$/i.test(str));
```

as the match() method is deprecated.

PS : the "i" flag in RegExp is optional and stands for case insensitive (so it will also return true for "hello", "hEllo", etc.).

Comment: Can you provide a link to documentation on match() being deprecated? A quick Google search doesn't return anything.

Comment: I read that online a few years ago, I'm afraid I can't find where exactly anymore.

Answer (score 21):

You do not really need jQuery for such tasks. In the ES6 specification they already have out of the box methods [startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) and [endsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith).

```
var str = "To be, or not to be, that is the question.";
alert(str.startsWith("To be"));         // true
alert(str.startsWith("not to be"));     // false
alert(str.startsWith("not to be", 10)); // true

var str = "To be, or not to be, that is the question.";
alert( str.endsWith("question.") );  // true
alert( str.endsWith("to be") );      // false
alert( str.endsWith("to be", 19) );  // true
```

[Currently available in FF and Chrome](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith#Browser_compatibility). For old browsers you can use their polyfills or substr

Answer (score 11):

You can always extend `String` prototype like this:

```
//  Checks that string starts with the specific string
if (typeof String.prototype.startsWith != 'function') {
    String.prototype.startsWith = function (str) {
        return this.slice(0, str.length) == str;
    };
}

//  Checks that string ends with the specific string...
if (typeof String.prototype.endsWith != 'function') {
    String.prototype.endsWith = function (str) {
        return this.slice(-str.length) == str;
    };
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var str = 'Hello World';

if( str.startsWith('Hello') ) {
   // your string starts with 'Hello'
}

if( str.endsWith('World') ) {
   // your string ends with 'World'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

ES6 now supports the `startsWith()` and `endsWith()` method for checking beginning and ending of `string`s. If you want to support pre-es6 engines, you might want to consider adding one of the suggested methods to the `String` prototype.

```
if (typeof String.prototype.startsWith != 'function') {
  String.prototype.startsWith = function (str) {
    return this.match(new RegExp("^" + str));
  };
}

if (typeof String.prototype.endsWith != 'function') {
  String.prototype.endsWith = function (str) {
    return this.match(new RegExp(str + "$"));
  };
}

var str = "foobar is not barfoo";
console.log(str.startsWith("foob"); // true
console.log(str.endsWith("rfoo");   // true
```

Comment: Any string that contains characters that need to be escaped for the usage in a regex (for example `()[].`) will break your polyfill methods. You need to prepare the strings with a regex-escape function. Or even better: Use a battle tested polyfill from `core-js`