# Is there a way for me to check if a string starts with the words "error" using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
if (data == 'error') {
   mvcOnFailure(data)
}
```

Is there some way that I could change this so I check for a string that starts with "error" or "Error"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to know that a string starts/ends with a specific string in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715309/how-to-know-that-a-string-starts-ends-with-a-specific-string-in-jquery)

Comment: Please consider marking one of the answers as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Try using a regular expression match:

```
if (data.match(/^[eE]rror/)) {
   mvcOnFailure(data) 
}
```

Comment: you might want to add  `^` if "it starts with"

Comment: You may just use case-insensitive match with the `/i` flag.

Comment: Or `/^[Ee]rror/.test(data)` if you doesn't really need returned matches.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(data.toLowerCase().indexOf("error") == 0){
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Now it checks if "error" is present anywhere in the string, not at the beginning ...

Comment: @Jan not true. It checks if it is in the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

As an update of Chris' answer I prefer

```
data.match(/^error/i)
```

which is case insensitive (will match slightly more than the questioner required).

*** UPDATE ***

Following Juicy Scripter's comment I now prefer

```
/^error/i.test(data)
```

As it returns a boolean, rather than the matching string.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
if ( data.toLowerCase ().substr ( 0, 5 ) === 'error' ) {
  ..
}
```