# jQuery match what I type against list

Tags: jquery

im trying test to see if what I type matches a list of strings, however because im using indexOf if I type `a` I still get a match if `a` is anywhere within the string, rather than if the first letter is `a`.

So for example I should be able to type `au` and just get `Audi` rather than something like `Yhjaukj` as an example.

[image]

This is my current code, it makes a list of strings from a select box options, then searches through these options when I type within an editablespan.

```
var $makes = [];
  $('#make option').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() !== '')
      $makes.push({id: $(this).val(), value: ($(this).text()).replace(/\((.*)\)/, '')});
  });
  console.log($makes);

  $('#marv_search_make span.value').on('blur keyup paste', function() {
    var $val = ($(this).html()).toUpperCase();

    var $result;
    for(var i=0; i<$makes.length;i++) {
      if (~($makes[i].value).indexOf($val))
        $result = $makes[i].value;
    }
    $('#marv_search_make i.hint').html($result);
  }).html($makes[0].value);
```

Comment: [`String.prototype.startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)

Comment: or use regex. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715309/how-to-know-that-a-string-starts-ends-with-a-specific-string-in-jquery

Comment: if you change your if statement to `if ($makes[i].value.indexOf($val) == 0)` it should work the way you want.

Comment: Thanks guys, @PriyeshKumar's suggestion worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is check the value of the span against each entry in the array and see if it starts with that value. If it does the `indexOf()` should return 0.

```
for(var i=0; i<$makes.length;i++) {
  if (($makes[i].value).indexOf($val) == 0){
    $result = $makes[i].value;
    return false;
  }      
}
```

Or you can use regular expressions.

```
for(var i=0; i<$makes.length;i++) {
  if (($makes[i].value).match("^"+$val)){
    $result = $makes[i].value;
    return false;
  }      
}
```