# Best way to check "begin with" substring in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
str.indexOf(substr) == 0

str.slice(0, 10) == substr
```

Which one of the above two is better? Is there any better way?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646628/javascript-startswith

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The performance of the first depends on the length of the string `str` as it requires scanning the entire string. If `str` is large it could take a long time to find whether or not the substring is contained within it.

If your input string could be large prefer the second.

Another option is:

```
str.lastIndexOf(substr, 0) == 0
```

This avoids scanning the entire string and avoids creating a temporary string.

If performance matters, I'd suggest measuring it for your specific data.

Answer (score 2):

A [(very) quick test](http://jsperf.com/indexof-vs-slice) suggests that the difference is probably negligible in Chrome, but that Firefox is substantially quicker with `indexOf` (for short strings, at least).

Comment: Safari has an even greater difference. Closer to 3x. +1 for the perf test. I was too lazy. ;o)

Comment: I never knew about jsperf.com (thanks), but when I run it win7 + chrome slice wins :-/

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, I'd say to use:

```
str.indexOf(substr) == 0;
```

Simply because it doesn't need to create a new string from the first. Performance testing would be needed. Could vary by browser.

Comment: Performance shouldn't be an issue. Creating a 10 character string will take less than negible time anyway.

Comment: @delnan: I agree, but the question was asked, and for me this version edges out the other simply because of the fact that the other creates a new String that just gets discarded after the comparison.