# to convert alpha numeric string to a lower case in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am reading a text field, and converting that value to Lower case and 
comparing to the array of words, if it matches it throws error.

But the problem is when we enter a text as a Alpha Numeric value, then I am not able to convert Lower case letters
and getting the Run Time error as "Object is Not Defined"

```
if(streetAddress != null){
    for(var k=0; k<notValidPostalChars.length; k++){

        var secondWord = notValidPostalChars[k];

        if (streetAddress.toLowerCase().startsWith(stopWord.toLowerCase())) {
            alert("Invalid Error Message");
            document.getElementById("address").focus();
        return false;
        }

    }
}
```

In the above Example, streetAddress may contain the Alpha Numeric as well and it might be in the Lower case or Upper case letters.

This will be entered by the End users and notValidPostalChars is an Array consisting of all the Pre defined Words with UPPER CASE letters

Comment: how do you assign a value to `streetAddress` ? what is in `stopWord` (*maybe it should be `secondWord`*) ?

Comment: If you are getting the value of a form control, it is always a string even if it contains digits. Show some sample input and errors.

Comment: alert(streetAddress.toLowerCase()); for debugging ans same for stopword

Comment: Alpha numeric strings are able to convert to lowercase: http://jsfiddle.net/jMBqX/. So, perhaps there's another problem?

Comment: Please try to supply clear mesSages to your users: 'Not invalid mesage' means it's a valid message.

Comment: if your stopWord is some example div id then simply add some dummy character like div id='aWORD'

Comment: @peterp, I think you are correct

Comment: @harigm I assume you have a function startsWith defined? [startsWith](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646628/javascript-startswith) is not core javascript. Instead it is indexOf()===0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe `stopWord` is not defined?

```
var secondWord = notValidPostalChars[k];
if (streetAddress.toLowerCase().startsWith(stopWord.toLowerCase())) {
//                                         ^did you mean secondWord?
   alert("Not invalid mesage");
//       ^ did you mean 'invalid message / not a valid message'?
   document.getElementById("address").focus();
   return false;
}
```

Comment: SopWord is your secondWord, I am reading the data from the array and comparing one by one

Comment: Why then, are you assigning `secondWord` in the loop?

Comment: Read the Street address from the jsp page, Not valid Postal code is an array which has all Not valid Characters, i am reading one item from array and checking whether if street address is starting with it or not??

Comment: No, that's not what you do: you compare the first character of `streetAddress` to `stopWord` - whatever that may be. Try `streetAddress.toLowerCase().startsWith(secondWord.toLowerCase())`

Comment: Let me try this now, In the mean time, one of the second word array item has "/" character, do you suspect this might be the reason for the "Object is Not Defined"

Comment: I don't think so (`'/'.toLowerCase()` is no problem). I think you should check the `startsWith` function. Test without it, using: `streetAddress.substr(0,1).toLowerCase() === secondWord.toLowerCase()`