# Get current pathname using JavaScript

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following JavaScript to get the pathname to show a link is selected:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;

    $(document).ready(function ()
    {

        $('ul#ui-ajax-tabs li a').each(function()
        {
            if ($(this).attr('href') == pathname)
            {
                $(this).parents('li').addClass('selected');
            }
        });
    });
```

However it has problems if that URL has extra parameters such as `/` on the end of the url or additional parameters (see examples below) Is it possible to check if the link matches part of the url so for example:

The Link is: `/Organisations/Journal/`

And the Current page is: `/Organisations/Journal/Edit/21`

This would class as being selected as it matches part of the url!

Comment: startsWith method definitions from this question may help to match urls if I understood your question correctly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646628/javascript-startswith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably use `indexOf` to check if the `pathname` starts with the value of the `href` attribute:

```
if (pathname.indexOf($(this).attr('href')) == 0) {
    ...
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf for more information on the `indexOf` method.

Answer (score 4):

```
window.location.pathname.match('^/Organisations/Journal/');
```

The `^` character matches the beginning of the string.