# Is the Regex right against what am I trying to do?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, webserver

I am creating a reusable node.js **NavigationController** class so I can reuse this in other server side projects If I may need or someone else may find it useful.

Here's the use case.

```
var navController = new NavigationController({
    routes : {
        '/user/:action/:anything' : 'UserController',
        '/app/:action' : 'AppController',
        '/file/:action' : 'FileController',
        '/feedback/:action' : 'FeedbackController',
        '/:anything' : 'ErrorController'
    },
    ErrorController : 'ErrorController'
});
navController.init();
```

The user upon server request can call this function of that object.

```
navController.navigate(req, res);
```

Now this and controllers are being called rightly. The thing under **navigate(req, res)** function which is a part of calling appropriate controller object based on URL is defined as function named **getRouteByPath(path)**. This private function will get the route and will allow **navigate(req, res)** function to get controller class name to call.

```
var getRouteByPath = function(path) {
    for(var route in config.routes) {
        var routeRegex = '';

        var routeParts = route.split('/');

        for(var rp = 0; rp < routeParts.length; rp++) {

            // checking if route part starts with :
            if(routeParts[rp].indexOf(':') === 0) {

                // this is "anything" part
                routeRegex += '[/]?([A-Za-z0-9]*)';

            } else if(routeParts[rp] != "") {
                routeRegex += '[/]?' + routeParts[rp];
            }
        }

        var routeRegexResult = path.match(routeRegex);
        if(routeRegexResult) {
            console.log(routeRegexResult);
            return route;
        }
    }
    return null;
};
```

I am too worried about this function as if this is the right way to do that?

Comment: This question belongs to [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: By that definition of posting questions in appropriate sites, StackOverflow should only have questions related to stacks which is overflowed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some flaws:

- Why do you use the slash as a character class (`[/]`)? No need to do that, only in regex literals you'd need to escape it with a backslash (like `/\//g`). Just use a single "`/`" instead (`new RegExp("/", "g")`).
- `.indexOf(<string>)==0` does work, but searches the whole string and is not very efficient. Better use [startswith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646628/javascript-startswith), in your case `routePart.charAt(0)==":"`
- `<string>.match(<string>)` - I recommend building a new [`RegExp` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/) and use [`.test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test), as you don't want to *match* - there is also no need to build capturing groups, I think, because you only return the route string but no matches (okay, you log them).
- You want to check if the whole `path` matches your regexp? Dont forget to add `^` and `$`. Your current regex for the AppController also matches a route like `/user/app/example`.
- Why is your slash (and only the slash) optional (`/?`)? Not only I don't think this is what you want, but it also opens the doors to [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) when building regexes like `/\/?user\/?([A-Za-z0-9]*)\/?([A-Za-z0-9]*)/`

  To escape that, you would need to make the whole group optional: `(?:/([^/]*))?`.
- Also, you should build the regexes only once (on initialisation) and store them in a cache, instead of building them each time you call `getRouteByPath`. The compilation of the `RegExp` is somewhere hidden in your code, although it needs to happen.

Comment: Don't use `exec` here, use `RegExp.prototype.test`. Also `routePart.indexOf(':') == 0` is better written as `routePart.charAt(0) == ':'`.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I meant :-) Also going to add the indexOf thing

Comment: [/]? is there because if the route defined is like /user/:action/:anything and user request an URL /user/me or /uer/me/you, the controller will be invoked at both requests. Is that not the normal way of doing this?

Comment: Can you also explain this point? "Why do you use the slash (/) as a character class? No need to do that, only in regex literals you'd need to escape it with a backslash."

Comment: There is a need of capturing groups because I want to get arguments to pass to controllers.

Comment: I've expanded the section on the optional slash (please read the linked article). `|` The point is that you don't need a character class for single characters. I'd like to know why you've used one. `|` If you want to get the matched arguments, you need to pass them to the controllers somehow. Currently you only return the route string

Comment: Great guide! Still your first point isn't clear to me and why do you prefer me RegExp object?

Comment: Every invocation of `match` with a string creates one, and that "compilation" is unnoticed in your code altough being a comparatively massive computation. See also my last point

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14084/discussion-between-umair-ashraf-and-bergi)

Answer (score 0):

A few notes:

```
routeRegex += '[/]?([A-Za-z0-9]*)';
```

says the routes may or may not be present `//` will match maybe a `+` is more suited than a `*`.

Also since I thin `_` is allowed in a web route

Your `.split('/')`, will remove all `/` from the route so it shouldn't be in split list

Comment: [/]? is there because if the route defined is like /user/:action/:anything and user request an URL /user/me or /uer/me/you, the controller will be invoked at both requests. Is that not the normal way of doing this?

Comment: Right my brain censored out the fact you append them all together, also `[/]?` says it may or may not be present, don't we always want it present?