# javascript if condition manipulation

Tags: javascript, extjs3

I need some help with my JS logic here.
So basically I am getting a bunch of permissions and storing them as follows:

```
for( var i=0 ; i<permissions.length ; i++ ) {
    p[permissions[i].PERMISSION] = true;
}
```

The values of the permissions are as follows

p.SELECT_USER,

p.INSERT_USER,

p.UPDATE_USER, etc and so on

Now I want to display/hide a window  based on the value of permissions.
I need some logic help in my if condition
So basically I want something like,

```
if( 'permissions beigns with the word SELECT' && 'permissions does not begin with any other word' ) {
    this.window.hide()
} else {
    this.window.show()
}
```

is there any efficient way I cant do this by modifying my for loop?

Comment: So are you worried about the security implications of storing permissions in clear text?

Comment: "is there any efficient way" --- when person says that, it means that they **already have** working solution that is proven inefficient. Do you have any?

Comment: I have about 50 permissions and I cannot include them one by one in a if condition , maybe efficient is a wrong word, shorter way would be the right one

Comment: Could you please show us what that ominous `permissions` array contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if( /^SELECT/.test(/*some permissionvalue*/) ) { /*...*/ }
```

would be pretty short and I suppose efficient enough?

Other idea (one liner replaces your code, if `hide` and `show` are existing methods contained by `this.window`):

```
this.window[ /^SELECT/.test(/*some permissionvalue*/) ? 'hide' : 'show' ]();
```

`/^SELECT/.test(/*some permissionvalue*/)` in both suggestion means: *test if the given value starts with 'SELECT'*. Like @Steve Wang noted, you could replace that using
`/*some permission value*/.indexOf('SELECT') === 0` to be even more efficient.

Comment: A slightly more efficient solution is to use String.prototype.indexOf, e.g.`str.indexOf("SELECT") == 0`, since regex usage is definitely overkill here.

Comment: @SteveWang: Please read about [startsWith](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646628/javascript-startswith). indexOf is much less efficient (even the regex is much faster)!

Comment: startsWith isn't part of String.prototype, so it's not implemented natively. Also, considering the length of the strings, I'd imagine that indexOf won't be noticeably worse than substr or slice.

Comment: For a naive test, see http://jsperf.com/string-startswith-implementations -- as always, it depends on the browser.