# How can I know if the variable starts with a special character in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript StartsWith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646628/javascript-startswith)

I have a function in JavaScript which takes a string as parameter.
Prototype:

```
function activateTab(pageId, tabCtrl, divId, otherdivId1, otherdivId2, disName);
```

I want to check if the last parameter, which is `disName` starts with "com".
For example: "ComSomeName", or "ComSomeOtherName".

Answer (score 0):

```
if(disName.substring(0,3) == 'com')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var n= disName.search("your string");
```

if it return 0 then start with your string
if it return -1 not found

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_search
first try to search in google then post question!