# How can I make javascript match the start of a string?

Tags: javascript

I have the following coce:

```
if (link.action === "Create") {
```

However my link.action could be:

```
Create xxxx
```

Is there a way I can change this match so it just checks for the start being "Create" ?

Comment: duplicate of "How to check if a string "StartsWith" another string?" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646628/how-to-check-if-a-string-startswith-another-string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

```
if (link.action.match(/^Create/) {

}
```

`^` is a special character: an anchor which matches only the beginning of the input.

More reading on regex in general: http://www.regular-expressions.info

Answer (score 3):

Just Check `string.indexOf(string_to_check)`. It returns the index number for a 'string_to_check', if it exists in the string. Any in your case, you want the string start with "Create", so the index should be always 0 in your case.

So, You can try this

```
if (link.action.indexOf("Create") == 0) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
link.action.slice(0,6)=="Create"
```

Will also work as you like as above mentioned methods. For further read [String object reference in java script](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp).