# Javascript - keep only values given list of attributes wanted

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I need a function that given a list of attributes, keep only the values that key exists in the list.

Examples:

```
attrs = ['a', 'b', 'c']
obj = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
return = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

attrs = ['a', 'b']
obj = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
return = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

This is what I have so far, but it is not working as expected:

```
this.keepKnownAttributes = function(attrs, obj) {
        let ret = {};
        attrs.forEach((attr) => {
            if(obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)){
                Object.assign(ret, {attr: obj[attr]});
            }
        });
        return ret;
    };
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object properties dynamic delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13875338/object-properties-dynamic-delete)

Comment: If a value that exists in `attrs` doesn't exist in `obj` should it be ignored or added as undefined?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to build a new object from your current array of keys:

```js
const filterObj = (attr, obj) => 
  attr.reduce((acc, key) => (acc[key] = obj[key], acc), {})

console.log(filterObj(['a', 'b', 'c'], {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}));
console.log(filterObj(['a', 'b'], {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}));
```

Comment: Not sure why creating an new object and spreading the keys every time is necessary. You can just do `acc[key] = obj[key]; return acc;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys()` and `.reduce()` methods:

```js
const attrs1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
const obj1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

const attrs2 = ['a', 'b']
const obj2 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

const filterObj = (arr, obj) => Object.keys(obj)
                                      .filter(k => arr.includes(k))
                                      .reduce((r, c) => (r[c] = obj[c], r), {})
    
console.log(filterObj(attrs1, obj1));
console.log(filterObj(attrs2, obj2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and pass in an empty `Object`. In each iteration just copy the property from `obj` to the `accumulator` and then return it.

Below version adds all elements that exist in `attrs`

```js
function test(attrs, obj) {
  return attrs.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue) {
    accumulator[currentValue] = obj[currentValue];
    return accumulator;
  }, {});
}

console.log(test(['a', 'b', 'c'], { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }));
console.log(test(['a', 'b'], { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }));
console.log(test(['a', 'b', 'c'], { 'a': 1, 'b': 2 }));
```

Below version only adds elements that exist in both `attrs` and `obj`

```js
function test(attrs, obj) {
  return attrs.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(currentValue))
       accumulator[currentValue] = obj[currentValue];
    return accumulator;
  }, {});
}

console.log(test(['a', 'b', 'c'], { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }));
console.log(test(['a', 'b'], { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }));
console.log(test(['a', 'b', 'c'], { 'a': 1, 'b': 2 }));
```

Here is the short arrow version

```js
function test(attrs, obj) {
  return attrs.reduce((a, c) => { a[c] = obj[c]; return a; }, {});
}

console.log(test(['a', 'b', 'c'], { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }));
console.log(test(['a', 'b'], { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }));
console.log(test(['a', 'b', 'c'], { 'a': 1, 'b': 2 }));
```

And tada. No need to use `Object.keys` or `Array.prototype.filter` if you just `reduce` the array instead of the properties of the `object`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.hasOwnProperty()` method. It returns true if the object is having that property. [Refer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

```js
var attrs = ['a', 'b']
var obj = {
  'a': 1,
  'b': 2,
  'c': 3
}
var obj1 = {};
attrs.forEach(e =>obj.hasOwnProperty(e)?obj1[e] = obj[e]:false)
console.log(obj1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through all the keys of the object and store them into an array with keys to be deleted. Later, you can simply delete the properties of the object with `delete`. You can get a list with all the keys using `Object.keys(obj)`.

```js
attrs1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
obj1 = {
  'a': 1,
  'b': 2,
  'c': 3
}

attrs2 = ['a', 'b']
obj2 = {
  'a': 1,
  'b': 2,
  'c': 3
}

keepKnownAttributes = function(attrs, obj) {
  let keysToDelete = [];
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    if (!attrs.includes(key)) {
      keysToDelete.push(key);
    }
  });

  keysToDelete.forEach(key => {
    delete obj[key];
  });

  return obj;
};

console.log(keepKnownAttributes(attrs1, obj1));
console.log(keepKnownAttributes(attrs2, obj2));
```

The example can be minified using some lambda functions

```js
attrs1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
obj1 = {
  'a': 1,
  'b': 2,
  'c': 3
}

attrs2 = ['a', 'b']
obj2 = {
  'a': 1,
  'b': 2,
  'c': 3
}

keepKnownAttributes = function(attrs, obj) {
  Object.keys(obj).filter(e => !attrs.includes(e)).map(key => delete obj[key]);
  return obj;
};

console.log(keepKnownAttributes(attrs1, obj1));
console.log(keepKnownAttributes(attrs2, obj2));
```

You don't actually have to return anything, since you modify the original object. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). First filter out the keys which which are present in `attrs` and then return new object containing filtered keys and its values.

```js
let obj = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

function remove(obj,attrs){
  return Object.keys(obj).filter(a => attrs.includes(a)).reduce((ac,a) => {
    ac[a] = obj[a];
    return ac;
  },{})
}
console.log(remove(obj,['a','b','c']));
console.log(remove(obj,['a','b']));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
const attrs = ['a', 'b']
const obj = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

const obj2 = attrs.reduce((acc, key) => 
  (acc[key] = obj[key], acc)
, {});
```

As generic function, would looks like:

```
const filterAttrsFrom = (target, attrs) =>
  attrs.reduce((acc, key) => 
    (acc[key] = target[key], acc)
  , {});
```

Answer (score 0):

this too works ;-)

```js
function someName(attrs, obj) {
  let newObj = {};
  for (var object in obj) {
    if (attrs.includes(object)) {
      newObj[object] = obj[object];
    }
  }
  return newObj
}

console.log(someName(["a", "b"], { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }));
```