# How to find li whose text starts with a particular string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, text

I have a function to get the `<li>` tag at the top that contains the `key` specified to it, anywhere in the text.

But I want to have the `<li>` that starts with the key specified to it.
Here is the code:

```
function displaySearchResult(key){
   var li=$('.listcontainer ul li:contains('+key+')');
   li.parent().prepend(li);
}
```

So how to get the `<li>` tag whose text starts with the specified `key`?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646628/javascript-startswith

Comment: @PabloSantaCruz that's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `filter`.

```
var li = $('.listcontainer ul li').filter(function() { return $(this).text().indexOf(key) === 0; });
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But its not working. The function i have mentioned is called on keyup event. So will it work on the key having more than a character?

Comment: @ChetanaKestikar, yes, it should work. If it doesn't, we'll need to see more code.

Answer (score 1):

Please check filter() in jquery.

[Filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

[Filter demo as specified in api.jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/5mzdZ/)

```
 $('li').filter(function(index) {
   return $('strong', this).length == 1;
 }).css('background-color', 'red');​
```