# Determine Whether String Begins With Particular Letters

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am trying to determine using javascript and regex whether a string begins with certain letters. If it's true I want it do something. I am trying to find the value "window_" in a particular string.

My code is as follows:

```
if (div_type.match(/^\window_/)){

}
```

This however is returning true when it clearly doesn't contain it.

Comment: Why is there a backslash before `window`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript StartsWith](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646628/javascript-startswith)

Comment: @Jack: because it can be `Window`,`window`,`bindow`,`5indow`, etc

Comment: @vol7ron Sure, but OP mentioned they want to find value "window_" in a string ...

Comment: It's not obvious from the question why that condition gives the wrong results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular expressions are overkill for this kind of string matching:

```
if (div_type.indexOf("window_") === 0) {
  // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to go the regex route, you can use `test()` instead of `match()` `/regex_pattern/.test(string)`

Example:

```
function run(p){
   return /^window_/.test(p);
}

console.log(run("window_boo"),   // true
            run("findow_bar"));  // false
```

Your use:

```
if ( /^window_/.test(div_type) ) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regex for that.

```
if( div_type.substr(0,"window_".length) == "window_")
```