# JavaScript - check if string starts with

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check if a string starts with the character: /

How can i accomplish this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a string "StartsWith" another string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646628/how-to-check-if-a-string-startswith-another-string)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
if(someString.indexOf('/') === 0) {
}
```

Comment: While this does work perfectly find, it isn't the "best" solution as it needs to iterate through the whole string.

Comment: @Tyriar - I most definitely agree.

Comment: So what would you guys recommend instead?

Answer (score 11):

Characters of a string can be accessed through the subscript operator `[]`.

```
if (string[0] == '/') {

}
```

`[0]` means the first character in the string as indexing is 0-based in JS. The above can also be done with regular expressions.

Comment: @JustinNiessner In what way is this unnecessary for you?

Comment: @JustinNiessner It's fine as long as string is a variable.

Comment: yep, since we're just checking for the first index of the string to be `/` and nothing else.

Comment: This is the best answer for *this particular case* since the search string is only 1 character long.

Comment: This seems better for this use case (checking if string starts with one particular character). This feature was added in ES5; here a reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Description

Answer (score 4):

It's 2022 and [`startsWith` has great support](https://caniuse.com/?search=startsWith)

```js
let string1 = "/yay"
let string2 = "nay"

console.log(string1.startsWith("/"))
console.log(string2.startsWith("/"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative to `String.indexOf`: `/^\//.test(yourString)`

Answer (score 1):

```
data.substring(0, input.length) === input
```

See following sample code

```
var data = "/hello";
var input = "/";
if(data.substring(0, input.length) === input)
    alert("slash found");
else 
    alert("slash not found");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/umairsaleemid/kXY97/)

Comment: Please check i have modified the answer and in my opinion its efficient. Up vote it if you like that.

Comment: If I am right this doesn't actually solve the problem. Please reread the question :)

Comment: It solves the problem..Check this fiddle
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/umairsaleemid/kXY97/)

Comment: This does solve the problem, albeit probably not in the best way.  Doesn't deserve a DV though.

Comment: +1 because this route is the only one that can easily be extended to be an efficient `startsWith` for large strings (even though I prefer [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) to `substring`).

Comment: If efficient extensibility is the goal, it [looks like](http://jsperf.com/javascript-string-begin-with-indexof-vs-substr/2) you're better off using `substr`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
   function checkvalidate( CheckString ) {
      if ( CheckString.indexOf("/") == 0 ) 
        alert ("this string has a /!");
   }
</script>

<input type="text" id="textinput" value="" />
<input type="button" onclick="checkvalidate( document.getElementById('textinput').value );" value="Checkme" />
```

Comment: My apologies =) Edited! I'll read the question properly before rushing off to writing an answer :)!

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "abcd";

if (str.charAt(0) === '/')
```