# JQuery if input starts with a value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am managing to check the value inside a postcode input field using the following:

html:

```html
<input type="text" class="cart-postcode2" size="10" tabindex="22">
```

JQuery:

```js
$('.cart-postcode2').keyup(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value.indexOf('BT') >= 0) {
        alert("is ireland");
    }
})
```

This is working great however I want it to only alert if it starts with BT and does not contain BT in any part of the value, does anyone know if this is possible?

So typing `BT2 9NH` will alert "Ireland" but typing `OX2 8BT` will not

Comment: Check if `value.indexOf("BT")` **is** `0`, not just `>= 0`

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript - check if string starts with](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15310917/javascript-check-if-string-starts-with)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript StartsWith](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646628/javascript-startswith)

Comment: Do you want the alert to on each key typed after BT is found or only once when it's first encountered?

Comment: The proper way for us is to rollback such edits. Proper way for you is to delete the question (which is quite unfair to @Adil). Please do not edit questions this way. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

You can check if string starts with `BT`, as `indexOf()` will give index zero if value stats with BT

```
$('.cart-postcode2').keyup(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value.indexOf('BT') == 0) {
      alert("is ireland");
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

a regex solution:

```
$('.cart-postcode2').keyup(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value.match(/^BT/)) {
      alert("is ireland");
    }
})
```

Comment: The regex solution was wrong - it didn't have the `^` to make sure it **started with** "BT"

Comment: yup, i edited it, but then it got deleted... can't hurt to have multiple options available for future ppl finding the thread tho :)