# Is there an existing or upcoming CSS3 selector for matching substrings of attribute names?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, css-selectors

You can do `[foo^="bar"]` to match nodes which have the attribute `foo` with value starting with `bar`.

Is there a way to match nodes with an attribute **name** starting with a particular string? The use case of this is to match all nodes with a `data-*` attribute.

Edit: the reason I'm trying this is to avoid iterating over all the nodes looking for these attributes (for performance reasons). I'd be using `querySelectorAll` and its Sizzle polyfill for older browsers.

Comment: jQuery's selector syntax is CSS-like, but it is not the same as CSS. Which type of selector are you trying to write? Neither library supports inexact attribute _name_ matching, but if you're writing JavaScript there are workarounds.

Comment: There isn’t a way with CSS, but there is a API in HTML5 to get data attributes using dataset http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#dom-dataset

Comment: @jli: There's no selector. `getElementsByTagName` with a filtering function will be the fastest thing that you can do.

Comment: There is no native selector to do that, and why you will find that most of the unobtrusive javascript libraries look for a specific data attribute.  For example `<a href="..." data-confirm="true" data-confirm-message="Are you sure?">` then you can write an unobstrusive javascript library that looks for anything with a `data-confirm` attribute, then attach an event handler to it displaying the `data-confirm-message message` and cancel the event if they click cancel on the confirm message.

Comment: It looks like there is no viable way of doing this via `querySelectorAll`. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 4):

One way is using `.filter()` method:

```
$('element').filter(function() {
    return $.grep(this.attributes, function(value) {
       return value.nodeName.indexOf('data') === 0;
    }).length;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QACsw/

Comment: `.lastIndexOf('data', 0) === 0` for extreme millerseconds difference as well.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: Won't make much of a difference, `$.grep` doesn't break out once the first `data-` attribute is found.

Comment: @Blender I know, I just meant that this operation would be a tad bit faster than `indexOf`. Here are the details http://stackoverflow.com/a/4579228/1331430

Comment: I didn't make this clear originally, but the reason I'm using a selector like this at all is to avoid iterating over all nodes/attributes (for perf reasons). Unfortunately anything less than a native solution wouldn't work, I think.

Answer (score 4):

It may be a little overkill, but you could write a custom selector:

```
$.expr[':'].attr = function (elem, index, regex_str) {
    var regex = new RegExp(regex_str[3]);

    for (var i = 0; i < elem.attributes.length; i++) {
        if (elem.attributes[i].name.match(regex)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
};
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LBHwr/**

So in your case, you'd do:

```
$('div:attr(^data)') // starts with
$('div:attr(foo$)')  // ends with
```

It's somewhat similar to the regular attribute selector syntax.

Comment: ya it's a little overkill but still an interesting one