# How to check prefixes in a string with dots separator

Tags: javascript

I would like to detect strings that have prefixes from another. In my case these are separate it by dots. For more understanding I give some examples.

I took a look over thesse posts but in my case does not work 100%.

[Determine if one string is a prefix of another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18582826/determine-if-one-string-is-a-prefix-of-another)

[How to check if a string "StartsWith" another string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646628/how-to-check-if-a-string-startswith-another-string)

I have implemented the following code but the problem is that the example number 5 is `false`

```
if(child.substr(0, parent.length) != parent){
  //different prefixes
}
```

I expect following outputs:

```
false:

1. parent="abc.xyz"
child="abc.xyz.pol"

2. parent="abc.xyz"
child="abc.xyz.pol.del"

3. parent="abc.xyz.pol"
child="abc.xyz.pol.del"

true:

4. parent="abc.xyz.pol"
child="abc.xyz.del"

5. parent="abc.xyz"
child="abc.xyzDel"

6. parent="abc.xyz"
child="abc.xyzDel.pol"
```

Comment: example number 5 is `true` not `false`, check it again

Comment: sorry, it was a typo. Already corrected

Comment: Would you please explain the criteria of true/false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while to figure out the pattern. Apparently you want to look at each sub-component individually and only return true if the sub-component is not matching. It appears that if there are more sub-components, that it is not being checked/scanned towards the parent string.

Eventually I got this function

```
function test(p, c) {
  const pSplit = p.split('.');
  const cSplit = c.split('.');
  const maxLen = pSplit.length; // I guess parent has always min # of parts
  for(let i = 0; i < maxLen; ++i) {
    if (pSplit[i] !== cSplit[i]) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Interactive example:

```js
function test(p, c) {
  const pSplit = p.split('.');
  const cSplit = c.split('.');
  const maxLen = pSplit.length; // I guess parent has always min # of parts
  for(let i = 0; i < maxLen; ++i) {
    if (pSplit[i] !== cSplit[i]) return true;
  }
  return false;
}


console.log('expected to be false');
console.log(test("abc.xyz","abc.xyz.pol"));
console.log(test("abc.xyz","abc.xyz.pol.del"));
console.log(test("abc.xyz.pol","abc.xyz.pol.del"));

console.log('expected to be true');
console.log(test("abc.xyz.pol","abc.xyz.del"));
console.log(test("abc.xyz","abc.xyzDel"));
console.log(test("abc.xyz","abc.xyzDel.pol"));
```