# Check if value contains certain string

Tags: jquery, string

I want to check if the selected  contains "color-" or "image-" and show the appropriate .

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jkxoE

Comment: Please post relevant code samples. What do you mean by `selected contains` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you ment was really to check if some string contains given substring. You can do the following:

```
childValue.indexOf('color-');
```

If the substring is present it will return the index where this substring appeared, if not it will return -1.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has not really anything to do with jQuery but rather with JavaScript itself. The "most clean" way would be to extend the String prototype in JavaScript with a startsWith-procedure:

```js
if (typeof String.prototype.startsWith != 'function') {
  String.prototype.startsWith = function (str){
    return this.slice(0, str.length) == str;
  };
}
```

Next you can use the new procedure with any string you want:

```js
if(childValue.startsWith ("color-")){
    //show pickColor div
}
```

Should you discover a better method to compare the beginning of a string you can simply change the prototype declaration once. That's far easier than changing every occurence of whatever you choose to use in the rest of your code.

**Sources:**

[Javascript StartsWith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646628/javascript-startswith)

Comment: But! Now I'm confused, `str.indexOf('color-') === 0` does exactly the same thing ?

Comment: Hey adeneo, yes but apparently this.slice(0, str.length) == str; is a lot faster then str.indexOf('color-') === 0
http://stackoverflow.com/a/646643/1173521

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use something like this?

```
$(selectChild).on('change',function(){
    var childOption = $("option:selected", this);

    if (childOption.is('[value^=color]')) {
        //show pickColor div
    } else if (childOption.is('[value^=image]')) {
            //show Upload div
    }

});
```

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/