# Alter an existing script that works

Tags: javascript, search

I do not want to use JQuery.  [Here](http://www.rgagnon.com/jsdetails/js-0089.html) is a simple piece of javascript that works that allows you to search a dropdown menu list:

```
<HTML><HEAD><SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
function searchSel() {
  var input=document.getElementById('realtxt').value.toLowerCase();
  var output=document.getElementById('realitems').options;
  for(var i=0;i<output.length;i++) {
    if(output[i].value.indexOf(input)==0){
      output[i].selected=true;
    }
    if(document.getElementById('realtxt').value==''){
      output[0].selected=true;
    }
  }
}
</SCRIPT></HEAD><BODY>
<FORM>
Search <input type="text" id="realtxt" onkeyup="searchSel()">
<SELECT id="realitems">
<OPTION value="">Select...
<OPTION value="afghanistan">Afghanistan
<OPTION value="albania">Albania
<OPTION value="algeria">Algeria
<OPTION value="andorra">Andorra
<OPTION value="angola">Angola
</SELECT>
</FORM></BODY></HTML>
```

The problem is that in order for it to work, the value of each option has to have the text.  I tried changing the "value" fields in the javascript code to "name" so that it would search the name only, but no go.  My option fields have numbers, and I cannot easily convert them to names.  Is there a way to tweak this javascript to work with names or better yet search within the option tags?

Comment: What do you mean by "name"? An `<option>` element has two relevant properties: `.value` for the value attribute and `.text` for its content.

Comment: Sorry I suck at javascript tried learning but never fully understood it so I may be using the wrong terminology.  So are you saying if I change value to text it will work?

Comment: I added  these two lines to as new options <OPTION value="123">123
<OPTION value="456">456 but the code still works...

Comment: No Namila, rename all of the option values to numbers and it will not work.

Comment: Bergi I changed .value to .text and still nothing.

Comment: Checked... but it still works :)

Comment: @user3187352: What exactly does not work then, how do you experience this? Can you make an example of how you renamed the values to numbers, maybe include them in your post by [edit]ing it?

Comment: These are the new values i used<OPTION value="658">658
<OPTION value="345">345
<OPTION value="678">678
<OPTION value="432">432
<OPTION value="976">976
<OPTION value="087">087
<OPTION value="123">123
<OPTION value="456">456

Comment: Simple, change the current list you see above to: <OPTION value="1">Afghanistan
<OPTION value="2">Albania
<OPTION value="3">Algeria
<OPTION value="4">Andorra
<OPTION value="5">Angola and search for the option names and it will not work.  Not sure what the confusion is here.

Comment: Namila why would I search a dropdown of NAMES using numbers only? Seriously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to change two things in the line

> ```
> if(output[i].value.indexOf(input)==0){
> ```

- use the `.text` property instead of `.value` at your [`<option>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement).
- make it lowercase to match the lowercased input. With lowercase `value` attributes and numbers you did not have this problem.

This script would be the result:

```
function searchSel() {
  var input = document.getElementById('realtxt').value.toLowerCase(),
      len = input.length,
      output = document.getElementById('realitems').options;
  for(var i=0; i<output.length; i++)
    if (output[i].text.toLowerCase().slice(0, len) == input)
      output[i].selected = true;
  if (input == '')
    output[0].selected = true;
}
```

<sub>I also have used an [improved `startswith` check](https://stackoverflow.com/q/646628/1048572).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

use this code, i have replaced "value" with "innerHTML"

```
 function searchSel() {
                var input = document.getElementById('realtxt').value.toLowerCase();
                var output = document.getElementById('realitems').options;
                for (var i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
                    if (output[i].innerHTML.indexOf(input) == 0) {
                        output[i].selected = true;
                    }
                    if (document.getElementById('realtxt').value == '') {
                        output[0].selected = true;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: I used your new code and it didn't work.  When I type in text nothing gets selected in the dropdown

Comment: It work fine with me.. did u try pressing ctrl+f5 for a full refresh after changing the code?

Comment: try moving the script section near to the closing body tag, usually it is the recommended placement..

Comment: try closing all <option> tags like this <OPTION value="8">hny</OPTION>

Comment: Yeah ive done that still no go. Are you using Internet Explorer or something?  I use FireFox and Chrome.  I dont understand why this is so difficult.  I am an expert in PHP I could code this with PHP but dont want the page the reload.  A way to search between the option tags would be best.

Comment: I am using google chrome Version 31.0.1650.57 m. I Tried this inside a asp.net project. But should work same for you since i used usually html controls.., just now i checked using a normal html file, it works fine in that also, i will paste the full code as a edit

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
var input=document.getElementById('realtxt').value.toLowerCase();
```

makes input a string.

```
<OPTION value=1>text
```

value is an integer.String will never == integer.
Change

```
if(output[i].value.indexOf(input)==0) to
```

to

```
if((output[i].value.indexOf(input)==0) || (output[i].value.indexOf(parseInt(input)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but are you guys testing out the code you provide because it doesnt work.