# AJAX pass custom field to jqXHR

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api, responsetext

Is there a way to pass an extra field to the `jqXHR` object? Here my situation:

I'm returning a `HttpResponseMessage` like so:

```
response.ReasonPhrase = "someString " + Resources.Messages.NoData;
response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NoContent;
return response;
```

But there are some cases I need to pass another `StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NoContent;`, for a different reason:

```
response.ReasonPhrase = "anotherString " + Resources.Messages.NoMoreData;
response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NoContent;
return response;
```

Because the messages are all localized (`Resources.Messages`) to the users language, I need an extra field to check for example if it equals to `"someString "` or `"anotherString "` or "...." in the `AJAX` `success` call back:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: '/api/testing/test',
data: jobject,
contentType: 'application/json',
success: function (data, status, xhr) {
    if (status == "nocontent" && xhr.statusText.startsWith("someString")) {
        // do something
    }
    if (status == "nocontent" && xhr.statusText.startsWith("anotherString")) {
        // do something
    }

error: function (xhr) {
    debugger;
    if (xhr.responseJSON == 'UnableToParseDateTime') {
        // do something
    }
}
});
```

The weird thing is, is that `xhr.statusText` doesn't support `xhr.statusText.startsWith()`. So equality checks on `"someString "` or `"anotherString "` or "...." doesn't work.

I've noticed that `responseText` is always empty in the `success` call back. If I can 'fill' that one from the server would be nice. If not, how can I have an extra field for the `jqXHR` object? Or define a few new custom `HttpStatusCode`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if `startsWith` is standard javascript, but you can always add your own function to the String prototype (see [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646628/how-to-check-if-a-string-startswith-another-string)):

```
if (typeof String.prototype.startsWith != 'function') {
  String.prototype.startsWith = function(str) {
    return this.lastIndexOf(str, 0) === 0;
  };
}
```

Which will allow you to check any String with `startsWith`.

---

To help with the question on adding to the jqXHR object, have you taken a look at the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR)? You can modify the jqXHR object in the `beforeSend` function of the AJAX call.

Comment: Do you have an example of a custom field in the jqXHR with asp.net-webapi? I read the docs yes, but not everything concerning AJAX.