# Angular.js resourceProvider returns $promise with data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, angular-services, resourceproviderfactory

Given angular.js service:

```
angular.module('mymodule').factory('Products', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource('/path/to/getProducts', {}, {
            find: {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: false
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

In the controller of `mymodule` I make `find` query:

```
$scope.findAll = function () {
    Products.find(function (products) {
        console.log(Object.keys(products));
        // ['prodA', 'prodB', ... , '$promise', '$resolved']
        for (var i in products) {
            if (!products.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
            console.log(products[i].description.someprop);
            // Got error: Cannot read property 'someprop' of undefined
            // Trust me: I debug this place. someprop is defined for all items except that two
        }
    });
};
```

It works fine but returns $promise and $resolved with data set, so that I can not loop through my data.

Angular documentations [says](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-resource/blob/master/angular-resource.js#L222) that the `Resource` instances and collection has these additional properties. But I don't understand exactly how to control it in my code.

What am I doing wrong? How to prevent it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indeed it's a bit more complicated when you're not working with arrays.

The `response` object sent back from the server contains:

- the `resource` object (your data + `$promise` and `$resolved`, that's what you get in your callback)
- a `config` object (the headers, the method used, the url called, etc) and a `headers` function
- and a `data` object, that's what we want ! It contains just the data.

But you will only get to see `response.resource` in your `then()`. You therefore need to intercept the response sent by the server to get the data instead:

```
return $resource('/path/to/getProducts', {}, {
        find: {
           method: 'GET',
           isArray: false,
           interceptor: {
             response: function(response) {  
               return response.data;
             }
           }
        }
    });
```

And then in your controller :

```
Products.find().$promise.then(
    function(products){
        angular.forEach(products, function(value, index){
            console.log(value);
        });
    }
);
```

Tell me if this works for you.

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/zLYi7ZJzBMJoQVrtJjqJ?p=preview)

Comment: stackoverflow doesn't allow me to award your answer with bounty right now but I'll do it in 20 hours )

Comment: @deonclem is there any way of setting this response interceptor as the default behavior for all $resource's? Repeating this code on all of them don't seems correct.

Comment: Check the doc : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http under the section "Interceptors". This will intercept every `$http` calls you make (as `$resource` uses `$http`).

If you want to only intercept specific calls, you can try : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23021416/how-to-use-angularjs-interceptor-to-only-intercept-specific-http-requests

Answer (score 0):

Resources return a promise, you can retrieve the data from the promise using `then()`.

```
Products.find().$promise.then(function (products) {
    console.log(Object.keys(products));
});
```

Comment: They will be, since it returns a promise... You can still loop over your collection. Read up on [promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

Comment: I got errors. Does It matter if I loop with simple for loop, not with ng-repeat? Updated my question with code

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is 'isArray: false'. So your products is not an array, but object. Set 'isArray: true' and you can iterate for(var product in products) all day.

Comment: My products is not array but object so I set isArray to false. If isArray is set to true but backend returns object angular throws errow Error: [$resource:badcfg] so I can not do this

Answer (score 0):

Try doing response.toJSON and it returns just your json excluding promise and resolve.

```
data.$promise.then(function(myResponse) {
    var actualData = myResponse.toJSON();
}
```