# How Search for a String in an array using javascript without using regular expressions

Tags: javascript

I'm a newbie to Javascript
please help me to solve my problem

```
function myFunction() {
var fr = ["banana", "orange", "apple", "mango"];
var n = fr.length;
var s = "a";
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
  if(fr[i].indexOf(s) != -1){
     console.log(fr[i]);          
  }
 }        
}
```

and the output im getting is

```
banana
orange
apple
mango
```

but what i want  is that it should print only the word that starts with the given letter/word

```
i.e., : apple
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are checking `index!=-1`, that is basically you are checking that `a` is present anywhere in string.

If you want to check that string start with `a` you should check if `a` is at `0th` index.

Check this in if condition

```
if(fr[i].indexOf(s) === 0)
```

This will give the expected output.

Comment: perfect ! thank you so much friend :)
you saved my life,i have been trying to solve this problem since 2 days.

Comment: This solution will be slow if `fr[i]` is pretty long. FYI, the better way is http://stackoverflow.com/a/4579228/961314.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that all of them are showing is because all of those strings contain the character 'a'.  If you only want to show the strings that begin the the character 'a' Mritunjay's solution is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring. This example will give you the first letter in the string.

```
 if(fr[i].indexOf(s) != -1){
     if(fr[i].substring(1, 0) === "b")
     {
         console.log("b found");
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

(For the record) Case insensitive *filtering* of your array on `/^a/i` (see [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter))

```
["banana", "orange", "apple", "mango"]
  .filter( function (v) { return v[0].toLowerCase() === 'a'; } );
```