# Angular conditional class based on URI

Tags: angularjs

I've added this to my side navigation's controller:

```
if($location.path() == '/goals') {
    $scope.goals_active = true;
}
```

This works perfectly fine and applies the active class with `ng-class`.

However, the problem I am now running into is with an id.

i.e. `/goals/b2dcf461-56f6-f812-bed0-538e1603a595`

How can I tell my application, in Angular (and using $location if necessary), to not only set `$scope.goals_active` to `true` when the path is `/goals`, but also `/goals/:id`?

I need some kind of a `*` operator but don't know how this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     if($location.path().indexOf("/goals") >= 0)
```

should match anything with /goals in it.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a Regex:

```
/\/goals(\/.*)?/.test($location.path());
```

Here is a quick snippet showing the test code in action:

```js
var urls = ['/goals', '/goals/', '/goals/12345'];

urls.forEach(function(url){
  var matches = /\/goals(\/.*)?/.test(url);
  
  document.write("url: " + url + "  [" + matches + "]");
  document.write("<br />");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't think you'll have URLs like `/goalsSomething` which should *not* be triggered, you can simply do:

```
if($location.path().match('/goals')) {
    $scope.goals_active = true;
}
```

Or what Scott suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Your safest route is probably to use a regular expression:

```
if( /\/goals(\/.*)?/.test($location.path()) ) { $scope.goals_active = true; }
```

You can also use indexOf, but that begins to get more complicated when you experience routes with additional text like '/goalsasdf'.  [There are also a number of other ways to do this, with increasing complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646628/how-to-check-if-a-string-startswith-another-string).