# startsWith not returning expected value

Tags: javascript, string

I found another question to help me find out if a string starts with another string [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646628/how-to-check-if-a-string-startswith-another-string/646643#646643). I used Mark Byers answer.

However, I ran into a problem using this.  For some reason it's not finding the string and returning `-1`.

```
var response = doWork();

alert(response.lastIndexOf('/apex', 0));
if (response.lastIndexOf('/apex', 0) === 0)
  window.location.href = response;
else
  alert('test' + response + 'test');
```

The comparison returns `-1`, but the alert at the end returns `test/apex/IFE__IFE_ViewQuote?Id=a01i000000XobwRAARtest`.  Am I doing something wrong?

I added a test to fire AFTER the above:

```
var response2 = '/apex/IFE__IFE_ViewQuote?Id=a01i000000Xoc4tAAB'; 
alert('index = ' + response2.lastIndexOf('/apex', 0));
```

This returned "index = 0".

Comment: Seems to work fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/hmzpsxtw/

Comment: I suspect there's a space at the beginning of `response`.

Comment: I just changed the alert at the end alert('test' + response + 'test'); and there seems to be no spaces in it.  Hmmmm this is the strangest thing.

Comment: Could you paste the result of `alert(btoa(response));` please?

Comment: @Siguza L2FwZXgvSUZFX19JRkVfVmlld1F1b3RlP0lkPWEwMWkwMDAwMDBYb2M3SkFBUg==

Comment: It's possible that the literal `'/apex'` in `if (response.lastIndexOf('/apex', 0) === 0)` has an invisible garbage character. Have you tried re-entering that line of code?

Comment: @TedHopp That is very possible.  How might I get rid of that garbage character?  The text is generated as a response from a REST service.  What do you mean by re-entering that line of code?  Do you mean by hardcoding it?  When I hardcode the string, it seems to work.

Comment: I meant that the garbage character was in the code, not in the response. I was suggesting that you re-type the `if` statement. The `btoa(response)` pretty much rules out a garbage character in `response`.

Comment: @TedHopp I manually typed out the if statement by hand instead of copy/paste and it still does the same thing.  I imagine it could be a hidden character somehow in the string returned though.

Comment: @dphil The `btoa` string rules that out, that's why I wanted to see it. `response` is clean.

Comment: That would have been revealed by the base-64 encoding that Siguza asked you to post. Assuming that the code you posted is the code that's running, this behavior is a mystery.

Comment: Gotcha... Well crap.

Comment: Could `response` be an array with one element? That would explain everything.

Comment: Must be code leprechauns as I've not been able to duplicate the behavior.

Comment: I think I figured out a workaround using btoa.  Will the encryption from that ever change?

Answer (score 0):

So, I guess I figured out a solution that HOPEFULLY will work for all cases.  I used btoa to figure out what '/apex' would be and took the characters that matched between this and btoa of the response.  They matched up to 'L2FwZXg' (there was an extra = at the end).  This seemed to work.

```
if (btoa(response).lastIndexOf('L2FwZXg', 0) === 0)
```

Comment: Still, that doesn't explain anything. I suspect that `response` is an array with one element, which is the string. Array to string conversion apparently means `array.join(',')`, and with one element only, that would look like it was a string when base64-encoded or `alert`ed. But could you please try `alert(JSON.stringify(response));` and tell me whether there are `[]` around the string or not?