# Deleting javascript object properties not matching a string

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a javascript object that looks similar to this:

```
object {
  attribute[1424]1405: 149,
  attribute[1425]1406: 149,
  attribute[1426]1407: 149,
  attribute[1426]1408: 149,
  attribute[1649]2116: 149,
  attribute[1649]2117: 179,
  attribute[1649]2408: 119
}
```

I'm trying to remove all properties that don't begin with `attribute[1649]` (stored in a variable called `conditionID`).  Is there some sort of filter, similar to `!:contains()` that I can run against the object with a `delete` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not. Just use a regular `for in` loop:

```
for (var p in obj) 
    if (!/^attribute\[1649\]/.test(p))
        delete obj[p];
```

(see [How to check if a string "StartsWith" another string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/646628/1048572) for alternatives to the regex)

Comment: Thanks @Bergi , that works very well when I explicitly state the string to test for.  The string I'm trying to test for (attribute[1649] in this example) however, is stored in a variable, which I think is what led me down the path of using `delete`.  I'm trying code like this, but am not having any result:
    `r = "!/" + conditionID + "/.test(p)";`
    `reg = new RegExp(r, "g");`
    `delete amounts[reg];`

Comment: The `!` operator is not part of the regex, neither are the `/` literal delimiters. Anyway you should not use a regex here (it would require escaping etc), just use one of the solutions in the linked article for dynamic patterns.