# Create jquery filter in list (start with)

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to create an unordered list. I was planning to let people filter the list by typing a person's name.

I want a filter search that should begin with not contain & case sensitive.

```
var value = $(element).val();
if (value.length == 0) {
    $("#" + listid + "").hide();
}
else {
    //var value = $(element).val();
    $("#" + listid + "").show();
    $("#" + listid + " > li").each(function () {
        if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(value, "i")) > -1) {
            $(this).show();
        }
        else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
}
```

Does anyone know of a good way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand *i want a filter search should be begin with not contain & case sensitive*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the following function to see if the string starts with a given value

```
function stringStartsWith(string, prefix) {
  return string.slice(0, prefix.length) == prefix;
}
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646628/how-to-check-if-a-string-startswith-another-string) for details regarding this function.

By default it is case sensitive. To make it case insensitive you can use `toLowerCase` on both string and prefix.

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/vf00q3ar/) for a working example using the code above to filter from a list box.