# Compare part of input with another

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I found this script:

```
<label>password :
  <input name="password" id="password" type="text" />
</label>
<br>
<label>confirm password:
  <input type="text" name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" /> <span id='message'></span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sprme2gq/2/

```
$('#confirm_password').on('keyup', function () {
    if ($(this).val() == $('#password').val()) {
        $('#message').html('matching').css('color', 'green');
    } else $('#message').html('not matching').css('color', 'red');
});
```

but I'd like to compare the first input with the second, but instead compare the exact value, i'd like to compare if it is on its way.

For example,
the first input is: "1234" 
and in the second is being typed: "12" 
in this moment i'd like to show it's still right, or at least, that it's almost there, not as wrong and only when the input are exactly the same say it's right.

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: So, you want a "help guess my password" routine?

Comment: You need implementation of "1234".startswith("12") check that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646628/how-to-check-if-a-string-startswith-another-string

Comment: @LOTUSMS, please do not use the [tag:jquery-validate] tag when the question has absolutely nothing to do with this plugin. Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply check if the Password1 begins with Password2

```
$('#confirm_password').on('keyup', function () {
    var p1 = $(this).val(),
        p2 = $('#password').val();

    if (p2 === '') {
        notify('');
        return;
    }
    if (p1 === p2) {
        notify('matching', 'green');
        return;
    }
    if (p1.indexOf(p2) === 0) {
        notify('waiting', 'yellow');
        return;    
    }
    notify('not matching', 'red')

    function notify(message, color) {
        $('#message').html(message).css('color', color);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I just think it's to compare the password with the confirmation but the code is comparing the confirmation with password, but it help me a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

```
function AlmostThere(pwd, pwdConfirm) {
   var confirmLength = pwdConfirm.length;
   var partialPwd = pwd.substr(0, confirmLength);
   return pwdConfirm ==partialPwd;
}
$('#confirm_password').on('keyup', function() {
   if (AlmostThere($('#password').val(),$(this).val())) {
      $('#message').html('matching').css('color', 'green');
   } else $('#message').html('not matching').css('color', 'red');
});
```

Comment: +1 for your answer. Fiddle update with above answer with some minor change http://jsfiddle.net/sprme2gq/3/

Answer (score 0):

JQuery unobtrusive validations handle all such. U can use them instead writing your own. U can have a flag saying when you are first time inside box don't compare till it's right. Set the flag to start compare when inputs are same or on focusout or change of confirm password.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```js
$('#confirm_password, #password').on('input', function(e){
  changeColor($('#confirm_password').val(), $('#password').val());
});

function changeColor(c, p){
  var color;
  if(c === p){
    color = 'green';
  } else if(p.indexOf(c) === 0 && c != ''){
    color = 'yellow';
  } else {
    color = 'red';
  }
  $('#confirm_password').css('background-color', color);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>password :
  <input name="password" id="password" type="text" />
</label>
<br>
<label>confirm password:
  <input type="text" name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" /> <span id='message'></span>
```