# startsWith is not a function getting called for no reason

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    if (typeof value[i].keyword == 'undefined' || value[i].keyword == null || value[i].keyword.startsWith(keyword)) {
        out.push(value[i]);
    }
}
```

I am getting an error message saying:

> ```
> > TypeError: r[e].startsWith is not a function
> >    at js-cf2cc68….min.js.gz:85
> >    at fn (eval at compile (js-cf2cc68….min.js.gz:8), <anonymous>:4:1003)
> >    at js-cf2cc68….min.js.gz:7
> >    at p.$digest (js-cf2cc68….min.js.gz:7)
> >    at p.$apply (js-cf2cc68….min.js.gz:7)
> >    at HTMLBodyElement.<anonymous> (js-cf2cc68….min.js.gz:9)
> ```

How is this possible? I think I've accounted for everything.

Comment: is `value[i].keyword` a string ?

Comment: may mean that `value[i].keyword` is a number, or a boolean or a date or an Object or any other number of things that are not a string

Comment: [startsWith - Browser Support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Try changing it to    value[i].keyword.indexOf(keyword) == 0

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`value[i].keyword.startsWith("keyword")` because the parameter of start with must be a string.

So that will work better this way

```js
for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    if (typeof value[i].keyword == String(undefined) || value[i].keyword.startsWith("keyword"))
        out.push(value[i]);
}
```

Comment: parameter of start with must be a string ... or a variable containing anything that can be turned ino a string? like undefined for example `String(undefined)`

Comment: Yes you're right. All the more so since the null value test become irrelevant. well done. I've just fixed my code this way

Answer (score 5):

Found [a useful article](http://2ality.com/2012/03/converting-to-string.html) on this topic

The three approaches for converting to string are:

1. value.toString()
2. "" + value
3. String(value)

The point to note here is that approach # 1 doesn’t work if the value is null or undefined.

In my case, approach # 2 for some reason did not work either so the best option would be String(value)

```
var col = "rt_" + rows[i]["results"][r].ResultTypeID.substring(1); //did not work

var col = "rt_" + String(rows[i]["results"][r].ResultTypeID).substring(1);
```

Comment: toString() was a simple solution for me

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way that I can check if it's a string rather than have it error out?

checking the type?

```
var out = values.filter(v => v.keyword == null || typeof v.keyword === "string" && v.keyword.startsWith( keyword ));
```

or simply enforcing the type

```
var out = values.filter(v => v.keyword == null || String(v.keyword).startsWith( keyword ));
```

or if you use desctructuring, you can use even this:

```
var out = values.filter({keyword: v}) => v == null || String(v).startsWith( keyword ));
```

I'd reccomend you to use the Array-methods instead of manually writing loops.

- Imo. it is a better description of your intent (good for scanning over code).
- If this is a hot path (it's called often) the JS-optimizer can take advantage of knowing, that youre'just filtering, and optimize the code. Maybe by skipping the lots of integrity-checks for the Array it performs during your loop.
- And if this is not a hot-path, the performance-impact of calling a function a few times will even be hard to measure, in JS.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by calling `value.toString().startsWith(...)`

Answer (score 1):

I assume value[i].keyword is a string. String.prototype.startWith is not supported in older browsers. See [browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith).

To use it in older browsers, you can use one of existing [polyfills](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith#Polyfill). See also answers from [How to check if a string “StartsWith” another string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646628/how-to-check-if-a-string-startswith-another-string)

Comment: I'm using the latest browser so still confused.  Is there a way that I can check if it's a string rather than have it error out?

Comment: I would debug it with chrome, but console.log(typeof value[i].keyword); would also works

Answer (score 1):

## There's a definitely obvious problem.

(This is entirely for people who have a problem like this one, but they don't really understand)

Of course, just like many others are saying, **it's in the type.** If you don't know what types are (You likely do if you know this advanced type of stuff, but just in case!), its simple. The primitive types are `True`/`False`, `Undefined`/`Null`, `Numbers`, and `Strings`, any `string` type that is not empty or numbers not equal to `0` resulting in being `true` if put through an `if statement` on their own. Now that we've got that out of the way, its time to talk about `startsWith()`. If you run `console.log("Hey VSauce, Michael here.".startsWith("Hey"))`, it would output `true` to the console due to how the string starts out with a string. If you run `console.log(1234.startsWith(1))`, would occur with a `TypeError` due to `startsWith()` requiring a string. We can tell this is a `TypeError` from the error output. So, the problem above (that was already answered) was that the variable `keyword` wasn't being defined as a string, but rather any other variable, and needed to be defined as a string