# Check URL for given string

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to show/hide a div with a navbar inside of it. Whenever the URL has /profile in it i want it to show the navbar. At this moment I have this:

JS

```js
app.controller('MainCtrl',['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.isActive = function(viewLocation) {
        return viewLocation === $location.path();
    };
    $scope.$location = $location;
}]);
```

HTML

```html
<div ng-show="isActive('/profile')" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
```

At this point it only shows the div when its :

> www.randomwensite.com/profile

But when i go a page further its gone.

I want it showing whenever the whole URL contains /profile.

> Like this: www.randomwebsite.com/profile/shop/edit
>
> or: www.randomwebsite.com/profile/account

Any idea how I would be able to get that done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a string "StartsWith" another string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646628/how-to-check-if-a-string-startswith-another-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `indexOf` to find a string in a string

```
app.controller('MainCtrl',['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.isActive = function(viewLocation) {
        return   $location.path().indexOf(viewLocation);
    };
    $scope.$location = $location;
}]);
```

Comment: When i tried `indexOf`it did not seem to work, when i changed that out for `includes` it does work. Thanks anyways!

Comment: sorry what do you mean by out for `includes`

Comment: I swapped the .indexOf in this: `return   $location.path().indexOf(viewLocation);` to .includes: `return   $location.path().includes(viewLocation);` .