# Optimising Jquery: If href contains url from shortened links

Tags: jquery, optimization

I am trying to avoid a potential problem when I want to highlight all shortened links within a page. At the moment I have this code:

```
        $('a').each(function() {

            var urlHref = $(this).attr('href');
            var shortenedLinks = ["bit.ly", "amzn.to","goo.gl","t.co","lnkd.in"];

            for (var item in shortenedLinks) {
                if (urlHref.includes(shortenedLinks[item])) {
                    console.log('yes');
                } else {
                    console.log('no');
                }
            }
        });
```

This works fine as the result in the console is:

> yes
>
> (4) no

## The potential Problem

At the moment, for every link it runs through the array and compares part of the URL. This is fine for a small amount of URLS however I have about 80 URLshortener services, and what if the page contained 80 links that would be 6,400 checks.

I tried this with a few links on the page and all the shortened url providers and it took a while to go through them all.

## Question

Is there a way to speed up this process so I can check the array and part of the url without looping through?

Comment: This should be moved to code review :)

Answer (score 0):

**First some small tweaks**, the break is the resource saver

```
// define the array more global, otherwise you set the array every call.
var shortenedLinks = ["bit.ly", "amzn.to","goo.gl","t.co","lnkd.in"];
$('a').each(function() {
    // use native JS where you can
    var urlHref = this.href // was: $(this).attr('href');


    for (var item in shortenedLinks) {
        // use starts with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646628/how-to-check-if-a-string-startswith-another-string
        if (urlHref.startsWith('http://'+shortenedLinks[item]) || urlHref.startsWith('https://'+shortenedLinks[item])) {
            console.log('yes');
            break; // we've found a match, stop looping <-- this is the biggest win
        } else {
            console.log('no');
        }
    }
});
```

You can improve this a little more by adding the `http://` part in your array so you dont have to do them twice.

---

After that, **you can also first check if it is an internal link**. All internal links arent short urls, so you can skip those in one go, skipping the need to loop:

```
var shortenedLinks = ["bit.ly", "amzn.to","goo.gl","t.co","lnkd.in"];
function isHrefShorturl(elem){
    // <a href="/example"> is an internal link, continue
    if( elem.href.substr(0,1)!="/" ){
        for (var item in shortenedLinks) {
            // use starts with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646628/how-to-check-if-a-string-startswith-another-string
            if (elem.href.startsWith('http://'+shortenedLinks[item]) || elem.href.startsWith('https://'+shortenedLinks[item])) {
                return true; // when we find something, return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false; // fallback, return false if no matches
};

$('a').each(function() {
    if( isHrefShorturl(this) ){
        console.log('yes');
    } else {
        console.log('no');
    }
});
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted - it looks like a good solution to me. Any comments as to why I shouldnt use this?

Comment: My first round wasnt perfect (though not really downvote worthy (IMO)), maybe thats why. I've improved it anyway, used better names and added the internal link check :)

Comment: Haha thanks. I've got some to spare. Though I appreciate it, just upvote when you think it upvote worthy :)

Comment: @JamesG i dont know your real final target but if you just have to highlight the shortened links i'd go for the css-only solution

Answer (score 0):

you can directly get the anchors with href starting with your string like

```
$( "a[href^='http://bit.ly']" ).each //do something
$( "a[href^='http://amzn.to']" ).each //do something
```

but to check 80 domains you would have to query the dom 80 times,so you could join the selectors into one

```
$( "a[href^='http://bit.ly'],a[href^='http://amzn.to']" ).each //do something
```

If,as you post says,you are just trying to highlight those links maybe you can just use the same selector but in css

```
a[href^="http://bit.ly"],a[href^='http://amzn.to'] {
    background: #ffff00;
}
```

EDIT:
after some discussions and testing,looks like the vanilla javascript approach is the fastest in terms of perfomance if the browsers supports querySelectorAll.

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="http://bit.ly"],a[href^="http://amzn.to"],a[href^="http://goo.gl"]').forEach(function(e){
  e.style.background='#ffff00';//highlights the link
});
```

jquery's attribute selector is probably the slower on older browsers

still,the css option(again,browser dependent) would be the very best for performance and dynamically added links

Comment: I highly doubt this is better, the attribute selectors are expensive. At least to `$('a').filter("[href^='http://bit.ly']")`

Comment: @Martijn, the attribute selector is much more performant in this case, which is a bit surprising. https://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/0u7ccesj/

Comment: yeah, but the 'attribute selector' version has 2 options, and mine 5. You also have one external link (bit.ly)

Comment: Though, when we add a lot more, it's still fast. https://jsfiddle.net/9f8hqg2p/1/ I have the feeling i'm missing something.

Comment: eheh,weird :) what if a page has 1000 links(500 internal,250 shortened and 250 external not shortened),your solution would still check 1000 links,and cycle the array for a match 250 times for the shortened links and cycle the entire array an other 250 times without finding anything for the external non-shortened links

Comment: i did some more test,i guess jquery attribute selector is slow when the browser does not support document.querySelectorAll,in fact i edited your fiddle(i lost it ._.) and using vanillajs with querySelectorAll was even faster,i'll update my answer