# How to Filter an array of strings based on first word in the string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

With the following array of strings in javascript, is there a way to use the .filter to filter by the first word?

```
['Desk_One', 'Desk_Two', 'Desk_Three', 'Chair_One', 'Chair_Two']
```

For example to .filter(x = 'Desk_*')

```
 ['Desk_One', 'Desk_Two', 'Desk_Three']
```

Maybe this needs to be a regex

Comment: [`startsWith`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646628/how-to-check-if-a-string-startswith-another-string/646643) will do.

Comment: is the elements will always have underscore between  2 words?

Comment: Do you want to filter by first word of first item?

Comment: Always two words and one underscore, and there are groups where the first word is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `startsWith()` function like this:

```js
let array = ['Desk_One', 'Desk_Two', 'Desk_Three', 'Chair_One', 'Chair_Two'];

let result = array.filter((item)=>item.startsWith(array[0].split('_')[0]));
console.log(result)
```

Comment: `Desk_` is hardcoded.

Comment: It is hardcoded in question also. Let us ask for more details.

Comment: no in question he requested for by the first word

Comment: You'd need regex in order to assert that `Desk_` is the first set of characters in the string

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer. Tnx.

Comment: String method startsWith should be more appropriate in this case, regex seems like overkill

Comment: @Andrew regex always easy but a heavy operation.

Comment: You are also right. Let me update the answer again.

Comment: This is perfect now, thanks for hashing this out