# Check if the string ends with a question mark using jquery

Tags: javascript

How can check the entered input is a valid question format using jquery ?

for eg: i have a string "How are you ?" . and i need to identify whether it is a

question or not .Do that all i need is to check whether the string ends with '?' ?.  Thanks .

Comment: What have you tried to solve your problem? FYI, it has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: And what about languages like Spanish, where it seems a question should be preceded by '¿' as well as succeeded by '?'

Comment: I dont keep this question downvoted then , delete it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This will do the trick...

```
if (value.substr(-1) === "?") {
    // do what you need here
}
```

`string.substr(x)` will start at the character with index `x` and go to the end of the string. This is normally a positive number so `"abcdef".substr(2)` returns `"cdef"`. If you use a negative number then it counts from the end of the string backwards. `"abcdef".substr(-2)` returns `"ef"`.

`string.substr(-1)` just returns the last character of the string.

Comment: can you add little explanation how `substr()` will work in thid case

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Archer, better put it in answer

Answer (score 2):

If you want a cute endsWith function:

```
String.prototype.endsWith = function(pattern) {
    var d = this.length - pattern.length;
    return d >= 0 && this.lastIndexOf(pattern) === d;
};

console.log('Is this a question ?'.endsWith('?')); // true
```

Took the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1095209/1518344).

Answer (score -1):

You can use `\?$` regex to find strings ending with ? mark.

```
var str = "what is your name?";
var patt = new RegExp("\? $");
if (patt.test(str))
{
      // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: This code throws `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /? $/: Nothing to repeat`