# jQuery - ASP.NET textbox ends with .zip

Tags: jquery

I have a ASP.NET textbox. On text change or move to a different control in the page, I want to check if textbox value ends with .zip, if not show a text message that .zip extension text is required. I have tried the below, but not sure how to get the ends with .zip and show message.

```
  $('#<%=txtfilename.ClientID%>').change(function (e) {

            var value = $(this).val();                 
        });
```

Comment: right click and inspect the textbox in your browset to get its Id or class name, then you this to check text change or compare text in your js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript or jQuery string ends with utility function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095201/javascript-or-jquery-string-ends-with-utility-function)

Answer (score 0):

You could try [regex](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp). Something like this might meet your need:

```
  if(value.match(/.zip$/i)) {
    $('#warningMessage').show();
  } else {
    $('#warningMessage').hide();
  }
```