# How to implement a "EndsWith" on a string?

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string

```
var s1 = "a,$,b,c";
```

I want to check if another string ends with `s1`

So if I send these strings it has to return `true`

```
w,w,a,$,b,c
^,^,^,$,@,#,%,$,$,a,$,b,c
a,w,e,q,r,f,z,x,c,v,z,$,W,a,$,b,c
```

And for these `false`

```
a,$,b,c,F,W
a,$,b,c,W
a,$,b,c,$,^,\,/
```

How can I check it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280634/endswith-in-javascript

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
if (str.slice(-s1.length) == s1) { 
}
```

Or, less dynamically and more literally:

```
if (str.slice(-7) == s1) { 
}
```

Using a negative offset for *slice()* sets the starting point from the end of the string, minus the negative start - in this case, 7 characters (or *s1.length*) from the end.

[*slice()* - MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

Adding this to the string prototype is easy:

```
String.prototype.endsWith = function (str) {
    return this.slice(-str.length) === str;
}

alert("w,w,a,$,b,c".endsWith(s1));
// -> true
```

Comment: You should probably use identity comparison `===` in a prototype enhancement.

Comment: @Tomalak: Done, I suppose if you passed in an Array as the str argument, this would make a difference.

Comment: Your method is buggy. It fails if `str.length === 0`.

Answer (score 5):

This will add a Java-like endsWith method to String:

```
String.prototype.endsWith = function(suffix) { 
   if (this.length < suffix.length) 
      return false; 
   return this.lastIndexOf(suffix) === this.length - suffix.length; 
}
```

You can then do:

```
"w,w,a,$,b,c".endsWith(s1) //true
```

Comment: +1 I would store the `this.length-suffix.length` in a variable `l` and then return on one line: `return l >= 0 && this.lastIndexOf(suffix) === l;`

Answer (score 1):

Get the length of the string s1, then get the substring of last digits of the test string and see if they are the same.

Like this:

```
if (s2.substring(s2.length - s1.length) == s1)
```

Comment: Which browser did you test? `"abc".substring(-1)` doesn't work on Firefox

Comment: @BurnoLM I guess I was used to the way PHP does it, my update should work.