# jQuery script references

Tags: jquery, asp.net

when I write this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function showhide(master, detail) {
            var src = $(master).children()[0].src;
            if (src.endsWith("plus.png"))
                src = src.replace('plus.png', 'minus.png');
            else
                src = src.replace('minus.png', 'plus.png');

            $(master).children()[0].src = src;

            $(detail).slideToggle("normal");
        }
</script>
```

and reference jQuery library in ScriptManager:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" ScriptMode="Release" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

every thing is ok.but when I commnet above code and reference jQuery In head part:

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

debugger alert me that for `endsWith` : `Object doesn't support this property or method`

why asp.net has this behaivior?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line of your code:

```
if (src.endsWith("plus.png"))
```

You are assuming that the string object has a method called `endsWith()`, but standard javascript does not have such a method.  There are various extensions that add that method to the string object (it's a simple one to write), but you cannot assume it is there unless you've specifically added it to the String object prototype.

I can't explain why it ever works unless one of the two configurations has a library that installs this extension.  It is not part of jQuery.

Here's an earlier SO question about adding an endsWith() method: [endsWith in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280634/endswith-in-javascript) and I happen to like this particular post in that discussion: [endsWith in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280634/endswith-in-javascript/2548133#2548133).

Comment: I add reference to jQuery so endWith must recognize

Comment: @Nima - Huh?  jQuery does not have an `endsWith()` method.  The problem with your code is that `endsWith()` is not defined.  That is exactly what the error message is telling you.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the path to jquery is correct.  The ScriptReference path is "~/scripts/jquery" (relative to the application root) but your direct reference is "scripts/jquery" (relative to the page) and these paths may be different depending on where the page is located.

Comment: no it's correct.I drag and drop my script on head section and above reference dynamically created

Comment: Using drag-and-drop doesn't guarantee the reference will be correct at runtime.