# JavaScript: Validate form field (image extension)

Tags: javascript, file, validation

I'm trying to validate the file extension of a input type="file" field. But even if I upload a correct file it gives me error. I've read W3Schools and other sites and I can't see whats wrong with my code:

http://pastebin.com/GwE0aVaf - It's the IF-statement at the bottom of the first function.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in the if statement it will always be **true**. You got:

```
if(fileName.lastIndexOf(".jpg") == -1 || fileName.lastIndexOf(".png") == -1)
```

And one of them will always be true wich causes the whole expressiont o be true.
Probably you will want to use AND(**&&**) instead of OR(**||**).

```
if(fileName.lastIndexOf(".jpg") == -1 && fileName.lastIndexOf(".png") == -1)
```

The solves the imediate problem, but this type of check will always be faulty, since if the filename is some like *"c:\sample.jpg.zip"* it will be valid.

You should validate if the extension is in the end of the string with a **endsWith()**  function or apropriate Regex.

See more at [endsWith in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280634/endswith-in-javascript).

Comment: Thanks alot, I feel stupid. Need to get my sleep now I think.