# Want to change image src of ImageButton using javascript on client click

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I tried this first which is not working:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="minus.gif" OnClientClick="this.src='plus.gif';"/>
```

Another method:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="minus.gif" OnClientClick=" return changeImg(this)"/>    

 function changeImg(cnt)
    {
    if(cnt.src='minus.gif')
    {
    cnt.src='plus.gif';
    }
    else
    {
    if(cnt.src='plus.gif')
    {
    cnt.src='minus.gif';
    }
    }
    return false;
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Is it even executing the JavaScript? Quickly test by putting `alert('hi');` inside the function. It might be running the JavaScript then reloading the page....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you do not return false, on client click and you trigger the onlick on code behind. Just **return false;** to avoid the post back and you get what you try.

`<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="minus.gif" OnClientClick="this.src='plus.gif';return false;"/>`

### update

On your code you type  `if(cnt.src='plus.gif')`, but you must type `==` , not `=`

To avoid this type of error is better to place first the const, eg type

`if('plus.gif' == cnt.src)`

and the final code

```
function changeImg(cnt)
    {
      if(endsWith(cnt.src, 'minus.gif'))
      {
        cnt.src='plus.gif';
      }
      else if(endsWith(cnt.src, 'plus.gif'))
      {
         cnt.src='minus.gif';
      }          
      // to avoid post back return false
      return false;
    }

function endsWith(str, suffix) {
   return str.indexOf(suffix, str.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
}
```

relative : [endsWith in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280634/endswith-in-javascript)

Comment: onclick is a server side event, can we put javascript inside this? It is throwing an exception

Comment: @Charu My apologies, I mix up with the asp:image, this is asp:imagebutton.

Comment: @Charu Just return false to avoid the post back, and its work (just checked)

Comment: Hey this works, but i want to change the image again on another click.It is not changing. i have updated the entire code, it is working for first click only

Comment: @Charu Is because you have a bug, you must type ==, on the if.

Comment: It is not working for first click also after using == in If block if(cnt.src=='plus.gif')

Comment: @Charu is because you probably use the full directory of the image... (and not just the plus.gif). Place an alert to see whats on the src

Comment: Which directory? I have images in root folder parallel to this page

Comment: @Aristos what if I want to get Url from another control?

Comment: @جمشیدکامران Use javascript to get it and use it - This is usually easy especial if you use jQuery this days

Comment: @Aristos I am using javascript, i need to get the current clicked control id and then swap it's value with another server control. issue is i am not able to get the server control

Answer (score 0):

The following should work

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="minus.gif"  onClick="function(){this.setAttribute("src", 'plus.gif');}"/>
```

Comment: I guess I don't know enough about asp, I would think this would result in an HTML onCLick event, guess the downvote shows otherwise