# RegEx test for string ending?

Tags: javascript, regex, testing

I'm horrible at RegEx and I need a regex to test if a certain string ends a certain way. For example, if the RegEx tests for ending with foo, "somestringfoo" -> True and "someotherFoostring" -> False. It needs to be case sensitive and work with alphanumeric and underscore. Here is what I've got, but I can't get it to work:

```
var test = RegExp.test('/foo$/');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) is a method of the regexp object, so it would be `/foo$/.test(someString)` or `new Regexp("foo$").test(someString)`.

However, testing a string for ending with a certain substring does not need regular expressions, see [endsWith in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280634/endswith-in-javascript).

Answer (score 2):

You would do it this way:

```
/foo$/.test("somestringfoo")
```

Comment: I tried using that, but I get invalid regex:
if (/<span id="lastmessage" style="display: none;">Stephen</span>$/.test(xmlhttp.responseText)) {
mySound.play();
}

Comment: This is an invalid regexp, yes. You of course need to escape the delimiters.

Comment: @Stephen If you don’t need the features of regular expression but only a plain string matching, you should use simple string operations instead: `str.substr(-pattern.length) === pattern`.

Answer (score 1):

this should do the work:

```
function isFoo(string){
  var pattern = /foo$/;  
  return pattern.test(string);
}
```