# Equivalent of Right() function

Tags: linq

Is there an equivalent of right() function that I can use in jquery. I want to get records with fileextension xlsx.

```
 new Guid(context.Documents.Where(T => T.FileName == ".xlsx").Select(T => T.ItemGuid).First().ToString());
```

something like

```
 select * from document where right(filename,4) = 'xlsx'
```

I don't want to store the filename in a variable and later manipulate it. I want to be able to directly use it in my where condition. 'Documents' is my table name and "FileName" is a field that holds names of the file that I upload, now I need to get filter only the files that has the extension 'xlsx'. I tried doing

```
  guid temp = new Guid(context.Documents.Where(T => T.FileName.Substring(T.FileName.Length - 4) == ".xlsm").Select(T => T.ItemGuid).First().ToString());
```

but I get the error "Sequence contains no elements" error.

*** Update: Used the EndsWith() to get the information I wanted. This works now:

```
  guid temp = new Guid(context.Documents.Where(T => T.FileName.EndsWith("xlsm")).Select(T => T.ItemGuid).First().ToString());
```

thanks.

Comment: Where does jQuery come into this?

Comment: *select * from* looks more like sql than jquery, i wish i knew who upvotes this

Comment: What exactly is `document` or `filename` in relation to the DOM?

Comment: @lonesomeday was trying to see if I could use like a right() funtion in the jquery statement I had above.

Comment: @MichalKlouda the select * statement was just as an example on what I wanted, got nothing to do with jquery

Comment: @silverninja document is my tablename and "filename" is my field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`right()` is the same as [`endswith()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2548133/175679)

```
function endsWith(str, suffix) {
    return str.indexOf(suffix, str.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.slice` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)) function, taking into account that passing a negative value into it makes it cut the string from the end. )

```
var test = 'filename.xslx';
if (test.slice(-4) === 'xslx') {
  alert("Passed");
}
```

Comment: `.substring` does not take negative indices.

Comment: @jackwanders Fixed. In fact, somehow I thought `.slice` behaves like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
filename.substr(-4)
```

Using `.substr` with a negative index will return a substring from the end of the string.

Comment: Erm... isn't `substr(negative)` not supported in IE8? )

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for `[name$="value"]` selector documented [here](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/).

Answer (score 0):

There is not, you can use

```
var filename = "file.xlsx";
var extension = filename.substr(filename.length - 4);
```

or to get the characters after the dot, you could use:

```
var extension = filename.split('.').pop();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use could javascript `match()` which provides regex matching.

```
var filename = 'somefile.xlsx';
var matches = filename.match('/\.xlsx$/i');
if (matches.length > 0) {
    // you have a match
}
```