# How to match a substring from a string and equal it in a If Condition in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

HI all i have some where there is Departments and department has some data like this

```
          Department
           Casual shoe
           formal shoe
           sports shoe
```

so i want to write an if condition where i should write an if condition like this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON("/api/ProductLayout", function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (idx, ele) {
                $("<img/>").attr({ src: ele.ImageURL }).appendTo("#makeMeScrollable");
                $("#makeMeScrollable").append('<span>' + ele.ProductName + '</span><h4>' + ele.Price + '$' + '</h4>');
                if (ele.Department == "Shoes") {
                    alert(2);
                    //$(".img_main").empty();
                    $("<img/>").attr({ src: ele.ImageURL }).appendTo("#Watches");
                    $("#Watches").append('<span>' + ele.ProductName + '</span><h4>' + ele.Price + '$' + '</h4>');
                }
                else if (ele.Department = "Wallets") {
                    alert(3);
                    $("<img/>").attr({ src: ele.ImageURL }).appendTo("#BackPacks");
                    $("#BackPacks").append('<span>' + ele.ProductName + '</span><h4>' + ele.Price + '$' + '</h4>');
                }
                else if (ele.Department = "Belts") {
                    alert(4);
                    $("<img/>").attr({ src: ele.ImageURL }).appendTo("#Belts");
                    $("#Belts").append('<span>' + ele.ProductName + '</span><h4>' + ele.Price + '$' + '</h4>');
                }
             });
        });
    });      

</script>
```

now i ant to write an if condition for shoe where if (ele.Department == "Shoes") i should get all the data of deaprtments which has "shoe" in it,jow can i write an condition for this

Comment: Confused.. is Department a collection?

Comment: In your condition use "==" not "="

Comment: @LewsTherin yes department is a collection

Comment: yes i fixed the condition use "==" not "="

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use regular expressions:

this tests for *shoes* case insensitive. (match also "shoesprostore")

```
if (/shoes/i.test(ele.Department)) {
}
```

this tests for the **word** *shoes* case insensitive. (match "Big Shoes" and "Small Shoes") (edit 4)

```
if (/\bshoes\b/i.test(ele.Department)) {
}
```

edit:

this tests for the **words** *shoe* and *shoes* case insensitive.

```
if (/\bshoes?\b/i.test(ele.Department)) {
}
```

\b : start and finish of a word

? : the previous character may or may not be present

i (after the sencond /) : case insensitive

look here for more http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

:)

edit 2:

corrected grammar inconsistencies thanks to  my friend SandMan

edit 3:

maybe you could save the regex in global scope (before the `$(document).ready(...)` statement) using

`var shoeTest = /shoes/i;` then

`if (shoeTest.test(...))`

Comment: is ##if (/shoes/i.test(ele.Department))## working with firefox 3.6 too?

Comment: yeah, tested with firefox 3.6.28

Answer (score 2):

To answer you question about finding a substring..

I will try:

```
if(variableInQuestion.indexOf("shoes")!=-1)
{

}
```

And two of your if conditions use = not == you probably want to fix that.

**UPDATE:**

Looking at your question again..

```
"Formal shoes"
"Casual shoes"
```

Is it possible that you want an `endsWith("shoes")` method?
If so:
 [endsWith in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280634/endswith-in-javascript)