# Using javascript to make custom bookmark links in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bookmarklet, bookmarks

Before diving into building Chrome browser extensions, I'd like to make a list of bookmarks that, when clicked, use javascript to perform particular actions. I am not 100% sure, but I think these may be referring to as bookmarklets?

To start off simple, an example of something I need to do is:

- I'm currently viewing www.somedomain.com
- I'd like to click a bookmark and be taken to www.somedomain.com/?testinfo=visible

Meaning, whatever site I am at, it adds /?testinfo=visible to the url and loads that. It'll need to check if it ends in / already, so it doesn't end up with //, at least.

Much thanks.

Comment: What is the question here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand what you are asking for, but if you are looking for a way to check what a string ends with in JavaScript, you could create a string-prototype, as suggested in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2548133/678801):

```
if (typeof String.prototype.endsWith !== 'function') {
    String.prototype.endsWith = function(suffix) {
        return this.indexOf(suffix, this.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
    };
}
```

On the variable holding your URL, you could then do this to see if it already has a trailing slash:

```
if (myUrlVariable.endsWith('/')) {
   // Already ends with a slash, act accordingly
} else {
   // Does NOT end with a slash, act accordingly
}
```