# jquery how to compare character string to end of other string

Tags: javascript, string, compare

to check if stringA exists in stringB you may uses this condition

```
if ((stringA).match(stringB))
```

THe above detects the occurrence in any position: initially, in the middle, finally.

How to narrow the search to the end of stringB only?

I have tried preceding the condition with this:

```
stringB=(stringB.substring(Math.abs(stringA.length-stringB.length)))
```

but it does not work. pls help

Comment: I think you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280634/endswith-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
if(a.substr(a.length - b.length).toLowerCase() == b.toLowerCase()) {
    // b == last characters of a
}
```

If you need case sensitivity, just remove both `.toLowerCase()` methods.

Comment: needed to use b.toString() first, but you could not know it. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
function endsWith(str, suffix) {
    return str.indexOf(suffix, str.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
}
```

Comment: just copied from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280634/endswith-in-javascript